# Change folder permissions and ownership

Tags: command-line, permissions, folder

I would like the user to have full rights on this folder (as well as all sub-directories and files in it):

```
~/.blabla
```

currently owned by root.

I have found numerous posts (in this forum and elsewhere) on how to do this for files but I can't find a way to do it for whole folders.

Comment: Could anyone add a graphical method I wonder?

Comment: @fluteflute is there a graphical method?

Comment: `gksu nautilus` perhaps. I'm not quite sure and would like to know.... ;)

Comment: simply *sudo chown -R username foldername*

Answer (score 522, accepted):

Make the current user own everything inside the folder (and the folder itself):

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.blabla
```

Comment: very helpful for newbies (like me) when don't know what to type in 'usergroup' for `sudo chown <your username>:<your usergroup> -R <path to>/.blabla`

Answer (score 912):

Use `chown` to change ownership and `chmod` to change rights.

As Paweł Karpiński said, use the -R option to apply the rights for all files inside of a directory too.

Note that both these commands just work for directories too. The -R option makes them also change the permissions for all files and directories inside of the directory.

For example

```
sudo chown -R username:group directory
```

will change ownership (both user and group) of all files and directories inside of `directory` and `directory` itself.

```
sudo chown username:group directory
```

will only change the permission of the folder `directory` but will leave the files and folders inside the directory alone.

As enzotib mentioned, you need to use `sudo` to change the ownership from root to yourself.

*Edit:*

Note that if you use `chown <user>: <file>` (Note the left-out group), it will use the default group for that user.

If you want to change only the group, you can use:

```
chown :<group> <file>
```

Comment: It should be said that "sudo" is required for chown.

Comment: fatanstic. You should consider maybe replacing 'user:user' by username.

Comment: Although I have changed the owner and group to Me and my group, I cannot edit the file acpi-support. Why? Thx.

Comment: The predefined variables helped me: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/dir`. Thanks!

Comment: BEWARE of recursively taking ownership of ANY directory. Think before you leap. Don't be `chown` copypastin' from the internet, kids. Just because you want to install a node package and it won't let you, don't `sudo chown -R` just because the fist hit from googling the error message says to. Reckless `sudo chown -R`-ing can kill your OS.

Comment: It needs to be said that using the `-R` option only applies to files and folders that exist in the directory already.  It does NOT apply to future creations.  For example, if you create another folder or file as root within the folder you've already changed permissions on, you will have the same experiences you're having now until you chmod\chown them again.

Comment: Do you know how to set a group for all new files?

Comment: much better than sudo chown -R $USER ~/.blabla

Answer (score 65):

If you prefer, this can be done with a GUI as well. You will need to open Nautilus as root to do so. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to access the "Run Applications" dialog and enter `gksu nautilus`

Next, browse to and right click on the folder you would like to modify. Then, select "Properties" from the context menu. You can now select the user or group that you would like to be the "Owner" of the folder as well as the permissions you would like to grant them. Finally, press "Apply Permissions to Enclosed Files" to apply the changes recursively.

Though it seems this does not always work for some operations in a deep folder tree. If it does not work use the appropriate terminal command.

[image]

Answer (score 32):

If it's owned by root you can do this

```
sudo chown <your username>:<your usergroup> -R <path to>/.blabla
```

Since ./blabla owned by root you need to gain root privileges to change that. That's what sudo will do. The -R option for the chown command says: this directory and everything in it recursively.

Answer (score 12):

you should try `chmod -R`

Answer (score 6):

First, check `demo.txt` permissions:

```bsh
# ls -l demo.txt
```

Out:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Aug 31 05:48 demo.txt
```

In this example change file ownership to `vivek` user and list the permissions:

```bsh
# chown vivek demo.txt
# ls -l demo.txt
```

Out:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vivek root 0 Aug 31 05:48 demo.txt
```

In this next example, the owner is set to `vivek` followed by a colon and group ownership is also set to `vivek` group, run:

```bsh
# chown vivek:vivek demo.txt
# ls -l demo.txt
```

Out:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 vivek vivek 0 Aug 31 05:48 demo.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use it `sudo chmod -R 777 /folderpath`
such as: `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/` this is for xampp htdocs folder access

Answer (score 2):

First `chmod -R` can mess up your system permissions if you do it on system file and directories by mistake.

Second `chmod -R` can mess up flags in those folders and is not a good idea to give permissions on some folders to all the users.

You should try and `chown` instead:

```
 sudo tree -fai ~/.blabla  | xargs -L1 -I{} sudo chown youruser:youruser {}
```

Answer (score 0):

sudo chown -R -ubuntu:ubuntu ~/PathTo/Folder/dist

Before Screenshot:
[image]

After Screenshot:
[image]