# How to change permission of a drive in an external hard disk?

Tags: permissions, sudo, gnome-terminal, external-hdd

I had an old laptop. When it got complaint I removed its hard drive and started using it as external hard disk. It has an 80 GB of memory allocation for the windows C drive partition. But now i don't need that partition anymore. But the problem is I am not able to access that drive to paste files into it. How can I make read and write permission to this drive using terminal?

Comment: Related: [Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to gain ownership of a drive you can use the chown command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/$USER/nameofdrive
```

This gives the user ownership over the drive to the current user without allowing permission to unauthorized users and `-R` makes this command recursive so that ownership also applies to all of the existing individual files on the drive as well and not just the drive itself.

You can also use `-R` to make `chmod` recursive as well.

To assign ownership permission to a different user and or group, just replace `$USER:$USER` with whatever `username:groupname` or `username:username` you wish to assign ownership to.

Comment: To be clear, replace both username parameters with your own username. `sudo chown -R mickeymouse:mickeymouse /media/mickeymouse/drivename`

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle You could also do this: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /media/$USER/drivename`

Comment: For anyone not being able to own change permissions despite using `sudo`, note that FAT does not support Unix permissions.

Comment: @Thijmen Correct! Permissions for FAT drives are determined when you mount the drive using `umask` options. Please refer to [this related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/389209/167115) for more details. Umask numbers are different from chmod but [you can use a calculator to determine the correct numbers to use that correspond to your desired permissions](https://wintelguy.com/umask-calc.pl).

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. This is an ok technique for files ON an external drive, but is the *correct* technique for files you just copied onto your computer FROM an external drive

This works: recursively (`-R`) change the `username` (the part before the colon `:`) and `groupname` (the part after the colon `:`) to your username:

*Note: be patient: for large amounts of data this can take many minutes. I just performed the following command on a directory on a **high-speed internal SSD** containing **966 GB of data** (as shown by `du -sh`) and **10.6 million files** (as shown by `find . | wc -l`) and it took **4 minutes**.*

```bash
# format: 
# sudo chown -R username_of_new_owner:groupname_of_new_owner path/to/dir
sudo chown -R username:username /media/username/nameofdrive
```

BUT, the problem with this is that it makes the external disk difficult to share between multiple usernames and/or on multiple computers, because each person on each system who needs access to these files must either have the same `username`, or must be part of the same `groupname`. Having the same username only works if it is the same person, so that doesn't always make sense. Having the same groupname is okay if it is consistently the same people using the drive, and they all add themselves to the same group with:

```bash
usermod -a -G groupname
```

BUT, if the groupname doesn't exist on one system, and just shows up as a number, such as `5000`, when you look at it with `ll` (`ls -alF`), then you can't easily add yourself to the same group because `usermod -a -G 5000` produces this error:

```bash
$ usermod -a -G 5000
usermod: group '5000' does not exist
```

#### 2. *Sometimes* better for files ON an external drive

So, that leads us to this solution: just give full permissions to these files to *everyone*:

```bash
sudo chmod -R 777 /media/username/nameofdrive
```

BUT, that also marks ALL files as executable, which doesn't really make sense. You don't want to arbitrarily mark every single file as executable, as that can pose a security risk, and also be annoying when every time you double-click a text file to open and edit it, it asks you if you'd like to run/execute it.

#### 3. Better still #1 (or best, if you DO need write permissions for everyone) for files ON an external drive

So, that leads me to my recommendation: give full permissions to *everyone* (`-a`, or 'a'll), but only set the executable bit (ie: use `+X`, NOT `+x`) if it is either a directory, OR already set for one or more of "user", "group", or "other", like this:

```bash
sudo chmod -R a+rwX /media/username/nameofdrive
```

`man chmod` says about the capital `X` versus lower-case `x` option:

> ...execute/search only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user (X),...

#### 4. Better still #2 (or best, if you do NOT need write permissions for everyone, ie: if *read* is enough) for files ON an external drive

**BUT, even better still, if you can get away with it:** if you don't really need guaranteed *write* permissions for everyone, just ensure you have at least *read* permissions for everyone on the drive, like this:

```bash
sudo chmod -R a+rX /media/username/nameofdrive
```

Then, apply permissions `-R a+rwX` only AFTER copying the files to your local machine from the external drive:

```bash
cp -r /media/username/nameofdrive/some_dir ~/some_local_path
# Now add `w`rite for everyone
sudo chmod -R a+rwX ~/some_local_path
# OR (even better!): just make yourself the owner now that it's on your local
# drive:
sudo chown -R username:username ~/some_local_path
```

### References:

1. https://superuser.com/questions/454795/how-can-i-do-a-recursive-chmod-only-on-directories/454807#454807
2. [my repo/file: search this file for `chmod` to find a bunch of my personal `chmod` examples here] [eRCaGuy_dotfiles/git & Linux cmds, help, tips & tricks - Gabriel.txt](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_dotfiles/blob/master/git%20%26%20Linux%20cmds%2C%20help%2C%20tips%20%26%20tricks%20-%20Gabriel.txt#L2246)

### Related

1. [my answer] https://superuser.com/questions/1271882/convert-ntfs-partition-to-ext4-how-to-copy-the-data/1464264#1464264

Answer (score 1):

The drives will be located in `/media/username` folder. Goto that directory using cd command. And then on terminal

```
sudo chmod 777 nameofdrive
```

777 assigns read,write and execute permissions to all users.

Comment: is that a good idea to assign such wide permissions?

Comment: Not working with dual-boot sistem.