# How can I change the owner of sda3 from root to my user to avoid permission problems?

Tags: permissions, disk

I installed Ubuntu, it is my first time on Ubuntu. Before I used Windows.

[image: Screenshot of GParted]

In this picture sda3 is my "D disk" like Windows. This disk should be for all my files. But the owner of this is root and I have problems when I use code editors like vs code.

[image: "D disk" properties]

I want to change the owner of this partition. How can I achieve that?

Comment: What problems are you facing while using softwares?

Comment: Every time asks to permission to save

Answer (score -1):

You can try to open the terminal app and type

```
sudo chown -R $USER /dev/sda3
```

Explanation:

1. `sudo` will ask for the `root` password once to get permission to make these changes;
2. `chown` does the change of ownership
3. `-R` makes is recursive to all subfolders and files
4. `$USER` uses the current user name
5. the last argument is the path of directory to be changed

Read more about:

1. [How to change permission of a drive in an external hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527304/how-to-change-permission-of-a-drive-in-an-external-hard-disk)
2. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/chown.1.html

---

Alternatively, you can login as root in the GUI and make the changes in the windows you showed us. Welcome to the world of Ubuntu. You may learn to love the CLI (e.g. terminal app) throughout the time!