# Root directory of the kernel

Tags: kernel, root, directory, programming

A newbie here. I am trying to set up Eclipse for Linux Kernel Programming. The [guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source) says set the project location as the root directory of the kernel. Where's the root directory of the kernel now? According to [Linux file hierarchy system](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/the-root-directory.html), it lists /lib as the root directory for shared libraries and kernel modules. I also see /lib32 and /lib64. However, I tried selecting /lib as the location and eclipse doesn't allow me to create the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For develop a kernel module you need the headers of kernel , you can install a package `kernel-headers-KERNEL_VERSION` like `kernel-headers-3.2.0-25` and the root directory is `/usr/src/linux-headers-KERNEL_VERSION`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to create an eclipse project in the root directory. However, it does not allow me to! Would you know how to give permission to the user?

Comment: Ok, I found how to [change permissions to a folder](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)