# Change ownership of external drive

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, gparted, disk

I just bought a new SATA disk and have formatted it into ext4 using gparted. When I ran Gparted, I ran it as root. Now, I can't write files to the drive because I'm not the owner of the drive.

[image]

The drive has a folder called lost+found . I'm primary going to store virtual machines on the drive.

Now my question is the following; What is the best way (most secure?) to make me the owner of the drive without "destroying" the permissions on the drive (I'm thinking of the lost+found folder).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added an answer but I'm not quite sure what you meant by "without destroying the permissions on the drive".

Comment: I thought lost+found should be hidden from writing from a non-root account.

Comment: Do you want to mount the whole drive as yours or do you just want to be able to put files on it? You could create a directory and set the ownership to you, then you could put files inside that directory.

Comment: It doesn't matter. What would you do?

Answer (score 5):

If you have root access then fire up your terminal and write

```
su
Password: (enter your root password here.)
```

Now mount your HDD (if not already mounted).
And type

```
chown -R "username_youwant" path_to_folder/folder_name
```

And now you're done!

**It is generally a good practice to mount your HDDs in the `/media` or `/mnt` directory.**

Comment: This doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 18). Does it make a difference if I'm using `sudo -i` instead of `su`? Is this relevant? Because `su` won't accept a blank password – and I never set any root password. Does it need to be the mountpoint or can I change ownership of any subdir?

Answer (score 2):

You go do this all through terminal, but I personally find it easiest to run my file manager (I use nemo but nautilus is default) as root and to change permissions graphically.

So open up a terminal and run `gksudo nautilus`.

Open the properties like you did in the screenshot. Since you're root now, you will be able to change it to your user.

[This, however, is probably a better place to find a well explained answer.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Answer (score 0):

You can now use Gnome-Disk (`sudo apt install gnome-disk`) on Ubuntu or (`sudo dnf install gnome-disk`) if you are on fedora to take ownership and edit `/etc/fstab` via a GUI with no terminal commands.

[image: Screenshot of Gnome-Disk on Desktop]