# HELP I changed permissions nothing works and I got locket out

Tags: command-line, permissions, root, chown

I ran this command `sudo chown -hR root /.`

and now flash is disabled, chrome does not work, nothing works, I cannot even access folder directories outside of the terminal. I then logged out and tried to log back in and my password for the log on screen did not even work!

These were the posts I attempted to read and follow
[Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

I have once before booted to the terminal, I forget the keypress function right now, but I believe this is the route I must take?

When I was logged on I received this error as I tried to follow the following posts' guidelines to somehow remedy what I previously did
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt

```
To change all the directories to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x):

find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;

To change all the files to 644 (-rw-r--r--):

find /opt/lampp/htdocs -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

but nothing worked from these commands except for this error message:

`sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and hav the setuid bit set`

I originally messed around with my permissions as I was annoyed with using sudo here and there and not having my commands fully work. I merely wanted to `pip install twilio` and `pip install flask` but previously when I ran these commands (with or without sudo) I received an error message telling my python3.4/dist-packages/ was unable to write the installation (I am using Python 2.7 - perhaps this is a problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the ownership of each file back to the way it was. Basically from what I understand from the man pages is that you made every symbolic linked file to the user group 'root'. The problem where it occurred was when you did the `/.` because that just means you did the chown recursively in the root folder. **You will have to go back through each link to set it with the right ownership.**

Good luck!

Comment: Could I run another command on /.

Comment: No, he made every file owned by root and in doing so reset the suid bits on any files that had it ( like `sudo` ), so now has no way back.

Comment: @phillipsk You might just want to remove all data from the system that is valuable to you and restart. You did a command on the level below `rm -rf /` but you'll still need a new installation.