# Nautilus as root cant change owner

Tags: nautilus, root

Running Nautilus as root on Ubuntu 14.04
When attempting to open properties window to change owner I get

ERROR:nautilus-properties-window.c:1839:schedule_owner_change_timeout: assertion failed: (NAUTILUS_IS_FILE (file))
 name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files

Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

In order to change file owner given that Nautilus has failed you will need to use the terminal.  The command chown as shown in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership) question will do what you need.  You can also type `man chown` into your terminal to get a detailed description of how to use chown.

Comment: Already done just after i posted the question. The question is how to fix Nautilus.