# Ladspa plugin folder locked

Tags: permissions, directory

I have LMMS installed. A audio sequneceq a bit simular to FL Studio. Now i have a problem with my ladspa plugins folder.
my ladspa plugin folders location is '/usr/lib/ladspa' i want add some new pluggins and i get an error! see for figure :[Figure](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5239536/Screenshot%20from%202015-01-28%2010%3A06%3A45.png) (i have not enough reputation so i do it this way)

What have i to do so i can write in the ladspa folder. 
I have tried `sudo chmod username:Anyone /usr/lib/ladspa` see [question about folder permissions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please do not change permissions or contents of system directories outside of your HOME directory until you are very familiar with the [Ubuntu file system and how permissions work](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions).
>
> Restricting access to these folders is one of the major reasons why Ubuntu is so secure and stable. In the worst case changing permissions of these directories can lead to an unbootable system.

Many LADSPA plugins can easily be installed from the Ubuntu repositories ([available plugins listed here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ladspa-plugin)).

In case a plugin is not in the repositories, and not installable from a Debian package obtained elsewhere we may copy files according to the instructions from the given plugin by gaining temporary root access using `sudo` on the command line:

```
sudo cp </path/to/source> </path/to destination>
```