# Who can change a file permission or ownership in ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown, ownership

Who has the privilege to change a file permissions or ownership in ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this one.](https://askubuntu.com/a/6727/294413) Or you can go for further details [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)