# Prevent Desktop Icons / Shortcuts From Being Deleted & Moved

Tags: 14.04, icons, shortcuts, desktop-icons

I am planning on setting up about 20 computers at a school with Ubuntu which presently have Windows XP.  The move should be easy as the computers are already locked down and the users simply open desktop icons to do things.  We use a program called Fortres on Windows to prevent users from deleting and moving icons.  Is there a way in Ubuntu to accomplish this either with a program or through changing permissions on the desktop icons?

Each computer will have three accounts on them: admin, teacher, and student.  We do not have accounts made for each user.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent files from being deleted using permissions.
What you need is :

> 755 (rwxr-xr-x) The file's owner may read, write, and execute the
>   file. All others may read and execute the file. This setting is common
>   for programs that are used by all users.

(learn more [here](http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions))

### Command line

Assuming a launcher icon "launcher" in /home/student/Desktop/launcher owned by admin (superuser)

set correct permissions using the following command :

```
sudo chmod 755 /home/student/Desktop/launcher
```

You can do that for the folder (and for all files in it) this way :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/student/Desktop
```

and neither teacher nor student can delete these icons (files, actually).

### Graphically

Right clic on file > Properties > Permissions (take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/6968/458410))

- **owner** "admin" access "read and write" (or "create and delete")
- **group** "admin" access "read" (or "access files")
- **others**        access "read" (or "access files")

For the "moving" part of your question, I don't know.

Comment: Do you know if there is a file that stores the desktop settings that your fix could be applied to which would keep the icons in place?

Answer (score 1):

I have only half response:

> sudo chattr +i /home/teacher/Desktop/* && sudo chattr +i /home/student/Desktop/*
>   `

That way the file actually in the /Desktop became "immutable", so can't be deleted or changed directory by no one.

But still be change position inside the desktop.

`man chattr` explain the other options

Comment: Do you know if there is a file that stores the desktop settings that your fix could be applied to which would keep the icons in place?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote `iconic` and it lets you save and restore icon positions. Basically after a new user logs in have it restore saved icons. You will need to "tweak the script" to have it run during login. Additionally it will:

- Allow you to move icons to any of three monitors
- Not suffer the "lost icon syndrome" that occurs when monitors of multiple resolutions are used
- Sort icons alphabetically, alphabetically with "Link to" prefix ignored, sort by modified date ascending or date descending
- Allow different grid size (columns x rows) depending on monitor, EG more on 4K monitor than 2K monitor
- Instant **Test** button for quick experimentation on column x row changes or reserved space changes for monitor left, top, right or bottom areas
- **Test** button will last for x seconds defined by you, clear all windows before test and restore them after test
- Bash script for easy modifications

You can get the script on [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic).

Here's the main screen:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

Visit the [github](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) page for **iconic** to see all the other screens, explanations and a copy of the script.