# permissions, changing ownership

Tags: permissions, sudo, root, chmod, chown

I have a flash drive which contains recovered files from my old mac, I installed Ubuntu just to recover these files, I have no other purpose for the OS.

The drive shows owner "Root" and the files are owned by #99, so I cannot view or copy the files.

```
sudo chown -R /media/(rest of path)
```

prompts terminal to ask for my password, to which is alternately says either "chown: missing operand after" OR sometimes it says "invalid username"

what am I missing

Also, in one instance I seem to have succeeded, in displayed messages of changing the ownership of every file in the directory, this took several minutes. Then I went to the dir and the ownership had not changed!!!

Comment: `sudo chown -R yourusername /then/the/path`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change folder permissions and ownership](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Comment: That command only works if "-R" is a user name ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo chown -R $USER:USER /media/(rest of path)
```

or

```
sudo chown -R $USER /media/(rest of path)
```

The 1st will change user and group to your current user. The 2nd only set your user to your current user.