# Changing file permission as root

Tags: permissions, chmod

I want to change this file to be read only ( 444 ).  At present it is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10313267 Aug  8 14:28 ron-video-intro-24fps-november-05-2015.mp4
```

I've tried the commands unsuccessfully:

```
sudo chmod 444 ron-video-intro-24fps-november-05-2015.mp4
sudo chmod -X ron-video-intro-24fps-november-05-2015.mp4
```

What is the corret command?

Comment: The file is not on a read-only filesystem by any chance?

Comment: I think you are correct.  The file system type shown with df -T is showing fuseblk .  Is this the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change folder permissions and ownership](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do file permissions work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work)

Comment: The issue is the file system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first command is the correct one: `sudo chmod 444 ron-video-intro-24fps-november-05-2015.mp4`

The second command will only remove the executable bit and the file will end up with permission `666`.