# Error when installing Unreal Engine 4

Tags: 16.04

**When Install UE4 in Laptop RAM 8GB CPU i7-3720QM Graphic Nvidia Quadro K1000M**

Enter in terminal:

```
sudo make UE4Editor UE4Game UnrealPak CrashReportClient ShaderCompileWorker UnrealLightmass
```

Output:

```
bash "/home/nguyenkhacthanh/Desktop/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/Linux/Build.sh" UE4Editor Linux Development  
Building UE4Editor...
Using clang version '3.8.0' (string), 3 (major), 8 (minor), 0 (patch)
Creating makefile for UE4Editor (no existing makefile)
Performing full C++ include scan (no include cache file)
Building UnrealHeaderTool...
Using clang version '3.8.0' (string), 3 (major), 8 (minor), 0 (patch)
Creating makefile for UnrealHeaderTool (no existing makefile)
Using bundled libc++ standard C++ library.
Target is up to date
Parsing headers for UE4Editor
  Running UnrealHeaderTool UE4Editor "/home/nguyenkhacthanh/Desktop/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UE4Editor/Development/UE4Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors
Refusing to run with the root privileges.
Error: UnrealHeaderTool failed for target 'UE4Editor' (platform: Linux, module info: /home/nguyenkhacthanh/Desktop/UnrealEngine-release/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UE4Editor/Development/UE4Editor.uhtmanifest, exit code: Canceled (1)).
Makefile:183: recipe for target 'UE4Editor' failed
make: *** [UE4Editor] Error 1
```

Comment: https://forums.unrealengine.com/showthread.php?315-Errors-building-the-source-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need root privileges to make Unreal Engine 4.

At first you have to type following in your terminal:

```
./Setup.sh
```

Then:

```
./GenerateProjectFiles.sh
```

And then type without options or arguments:

```
make
```

After building type

```
make ARGS=-clean
```

to clean any build target automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In my case UnrealEngine directory was owned by root, so `make` failed because of permissions, and `sudo make` refused to run as above. The solution was to change the owner to myself, [as in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership):

```
sudo chown -R $USER <UE directory>
```

then run `make`.