# Change permissions on file

Tags: permissions, apache2, magento

I want to change permissions + owner on a .htaccess file but how do I go about doing this? I have tried googling it but most answers are just for people looking to do it on a directory recursively.

I'm sitting in the directory where the .htaccess is.

```
httpdocs/downloader/
```

I login to the user I want the owner to be:

```
chown -R root .
```

then does this change the owner + permissions?

```
chmod 644 .htaccess
```

Thank you.

Using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change folder permissions and ownership](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Comment: @MadMike I don't believe that question is a duplicate, specially since OP says: `but most answers are just for people looking to do it on a directory recursively`. I know the answers are similar, but to someone new, they can't know the difference if it wasn't explained to them

Comment: @Dan The first answer on the linked question specifically address the usage of recursively changing the folder content or a single file. So that's why I marked it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To change ownership and/or access of a file, do:

```
sudo chown <user>:<group> /path/to/file
sudo chmod <owner><group><everuone> /path/to/file
```

Using `-R` when modifying permissions for single file is unnecessary (recursive changes make sense  when you modify directories).

A change to your .htaccess file's ownership and permissions can be made like this:

```
#go to the folder where the file is located
cd /var/www/mywebsite
#change ownership to the desired user and group
sudo chown wwdata:wwdata .htaccess
#change permissions
sudo chmod 644 .htaccess
#verify
ls -lah .htaccess
```

Comment: If you are the owner of the file, you do not need `sudo` to use `chmod` on the file.