# Set up upload permissions for a share folder on server via ssh

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, shared-folders, sftp

I have set up a headless home file server using Ubuntu Server 17.04. I access it over WiFi using SSH from my laptop running standard Ubuntu 17.04. I have found that SSH (SFTP) is sufficient for my needs for serving files (e.g. music and photographs) for my home network.

Now I would like to be able to upload files to a folder on my server's hard drive `/dev/sda1`, which is currently mounted as `/media/a`. It uses the ext4 Linux filesystem and I mounted it using the command `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/a`.

I can run SSH commands from the terminal (by logging in with `ssh username@servername`) and I can access the files via the GUI on my laptop (files > other locations > connect to server > sftp://username@servername). However when I try to create a new folder (say) it says

> Error creating new folder: permission denied.

I tried setting the permissions on an `upload` folder (newly created via my ssh session) with `sudo chmod o=rwx /media/a/upload`. However, when I now try to create a folder there via the GUI on my laptop, it says

> Error creating new folder: unknown reason.

**How can I upload files to my server from my laptop?**

**EDIT:** Here is the contents of my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file, as requested:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.100 2016/08/15 12:32:04 naddy Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
#AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

**EDIT:** The following is the output of the various commands requested in the comments

```
username@servername:~$ findmnt /media/a

TARGET   SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/a /dev/sdc1 ext4   rw,relatime,data=ordered
username@servername:~$ namei -lx /media/a
f: /media/a
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root media
Drwxr-xr-x root root a
username@servername:~$ id
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),111(lxd),116(sambashare),117(lpadmin)
username@servername:~$ getfacl /media/a
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/a
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x

username@servername:~$ mkdir -v /media/a/upload
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/media/a/upload’: Permission denied
```

Comment: What filesystem is on the drive, and how is it mounted?

Comment: It uses the ext4 Linux filesystem and I mounted it using the command `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/a`. Sorry for not adding it to the question before - didn't know that could be relevant - does this answer your question?

Comment: What is the configuration you added/modified `sshd_config`? What errors you can see in the logs?

Comment: I'm sorry @Jakuje I don't know what `sshd_config` is or how to access the logs. I'm sure I can find this information with Google though, will take a look and update the question.

Comment: I have the contents of `sshd_config` (in /etc/ssh/) - I haven't modified this file, what settings do you need to know? Or should I paste the whole file (if so - is there any sensitive information in here I should redact?)

Comment: I also checked `/var/log/auth.log`, reproduced the `Error creating new folder: unknown reason.`, and checked `/var/log/auth.log` again. No new logs were created here. Perhaps I should turn up the verbosity?

Comment: Add the output of the following commands when ran on the server, please: `findmnt /media/a`, `namei -lx /media/d` and `id`

Comment: What are the full access permissions (flags and ownership) of `/media/a`, e. g. the output of `getfacl /media/a` (or remotely with `ssh username@servername [COMMAND]`)? What happens when you run `ssh username@servername mkdir -v /media/a/upload`?

Comment: @muru David Please see the edit to the question with the output of the commands you requested I run.

Comment: @DavidFoerster sorry - system only allows one notification for some poor reason

Comment: If my answer doesn't change anything, it looks like there may be access restrictions in the volume mount options. Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `awk '$2=="/media/a"' /proc/mounts`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want a "sticky" directory like `/tmp` in which every user with write access can create entries but they can't change the directory itself or delete entries created by other users. The sticky bit has the octal mask `1000` or the symbol `t`.

To set the "sticky" or "restricted deletion" flag:

```
sudo chmod +t /media/a
```

To set the "sticky" flag *and* allow everyone to create directory entries:

```
sudo chmod a=rwxt /media/a
```

---

The [manual page of `unlink(2)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man2/unlink.2.html) describes the effect of the sticky flag on directories in its error condition section:

> `EPERM` or `EACCES`: The directory containing pathname has the sticky bit (`S_ISVTX`) set and the process's effective UID is  neither the UID of the file to be deleted nor that of the directory containing it, and the process is not privileged (Linux: does not have the `CAP_FOWNER` capability).

See also

- [What is the “t” letter in the output of “ls -ld /tmp”?](/q/432699/175814)
- [How does the sticky bit work?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/79395/47852)

Comment: I ran those commands but I'm still getting the same messages when I try to mkdir in the affected directory - permission denied (in terminal) and unknown reason (in GUI). At the moment I only have one user. Ideally I'd like to have one user that has full access to the server via ssh to upload, move, rename etc., and perhaps a read-only user for my media devices.

Answer (score 3):

Although restricting deletion of unowned folders as [David suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/930420/225694) is possibly a good idea for your usage case, it's not the root cause of your issue.

The o= switch for chmod indicates others (not user, not group member), not everyone. I don't think that's what you have in mind. To set read and write for you, you want to use the u= switch as in `sudo chmod u=rwx /media/a/upload`

Of course this assumes that you have write access to the parent directory Which your question indicates you do not. You need write permission to a directory in order to create a directory in it which is why you cannot `mkdir -v /media/a/upload` as you only have read and execute permissions to /media/a/

Note that since permissions apply to (U)ser (G)roup and (O)thers if you want fine access control you'll need to change the user or group or both from it's current root:root ownership. more on chown below.

If my user name was ivan and I wanted rwx access for me only on the media/a/upload directory I would issue the following commands.

sudo chown ivan /media/a/upload (which would leave the group status unchanged) or more generically

`sudo chown username:groupname /media/a/upload`

followed by

`sudo chmod u=rwx /media/a/upload`

Since others have access via the x permission to /media/a/ you should be allowed to traverse that directory allowing the change of ownership and permission settings on /media/a/upload/

For more on chown see `man chown` or https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown
For more on chmod see `man chmod` or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod or https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod

Sources:

`man chown`

`man chmod`

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod

Edit: The [Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership/6968) post goes into great detail on this topic.