# Sub folders owner does not change

Tags: command-line, permissions, directory, chown

New to using CLI OS.

So I tried changing the owner of a particular folder from root to my user so I can avoid errors of access denied whenever I would publish my dotnet app.

Basically, this is the folder structure.

```
myAppFolder
 |
 ->myApp
   |
   ->All forders that make the app(folders, .cs, .sln and the likes)
   ->publish
   ->README.md
```

When I use `ls -lart` on myAppFolder it says that the owner is the root. Though when I go inside and `ls -lart` in it some files/folders' owner is my user already. I figured that if I use `'sudo chown -R user myAppFolder'` it should also change the owner of all it's subfolders because of the recursive flag. (Correct me if I'm wrong.) But when I did execute the command the ownership did not change to my user. Is there something I'm missing here? Is my understanding of the used command wrong?

EDIT:
The referenced [Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership) is where I actually got the command I used, I just edited it to `'sudo chown -R user myAppFolder'` because I was already in the folder that contained *myAppfolder* which is */apps*.

Comment: `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER myAppFolder` - Formore see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership

Comment: Probably immutable bit is set for some of your files/directories, if this is the case, you'd have to remove the immutable bit first. Use `lsattr` to see file attributes and `chattr -i`. Take a look at the related man pages, `man lsattr` and `man chattr`

Comment: @mook765 so the only way for me to change the owner of that particular file is to remove it and recreate it, is that correct?

Comment: @vhie No, if the immutable bit is set you need to remove the immutable bit first, then you can make changes to the file. But I don't know if that's the case here, you never provided any meaningful output from `ls -l` or `lsattr`. So how can we know?

Comment: @mook765 so this is how it looks when I did the lsattr. http://prntscr.com/npm92m

Comment: @vhie On the few files/folders I can see in the picture no immutable bit is set. If the immutable bit is set on a file and you try to change the ownership of that file, you would get a `permission denied`-error. If you didn't get this error, then the culprit is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

try this command in your terminal

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/myAppFolder
```

this is duplicate of this question [Change folder permissions and ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

Comment: You need to `cd` to the directory containing `myAppFolder` first. Or use absolute path.

Comment: @GHOST
what is the difference in using a single `$USER` in using `$USER:$USER`?

Comment: @vhie Using `$USER:$USER` will also change the group while using `$USER` will only change the owner.