# How can I become the owner of a file/folder that root owns?

Tags: permissions, root

I had a bad habit of storing my wallpapers in **/usr/share/backgrounds**, and decided to move them all into **Pictures**. Well, the problem is that most of them are now **read-only** since they are owned by **root**. How can I become the owner of them, if root already owns them? I have already tried [How can I become the owner of a file that origins from another pc / user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17144/how-can-i-become-the-owner-of-a-file-that-origins-from-another-pc-user), but the settings do not "stick".

[image]

Answer (score 74, accepted):

1. Open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Now you are in your home.
2. `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER Pictures` and type your normal user password.

Comment: Or if another directory in your home folder substitute that for pictures. Worked for me and the subfolders as well.

Comment: the -R or –recursive option to operate on files and directories recursively

Answer (score 12):

You can do it via terminal or gui.

**GUI VERSION**

Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gksu nautilus` This will turn you into an admin account using nautilus. Now go to those files and change the permissions/owner so your normal account can use them. This sometimes not work. At least for me they work and in another PC do not. Test and see.

The GUI version looks almost the same as Dash, except that instead of saying "Search" in the search bar it says "Run a command". Here is an image:

[image]

**TERMINAL VERSION**

Type <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gnome-terminal`. Go to that folder. In your case it would be `cd "/home/alan/Desktop/Untitled Folder"` and type `sudo chown alan:alan *.jpg`. This will work because it will ;)

Comment: Thanks CYREX! The GUI version would never work for some reason, but running that in Terminal did the trick. Vanni was the first to answer (by 6 seconds), but I since you both had practically the same answer I up-voted yours too :)

Comment: @Luis The **GUI version** work on any Ubuntu's version or only for the 12.04?

Comment: @Lucio - I can confirm it works at least since 11.04. I tried that in 11.04, 11.10 and 12.04.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo su
chown user_name folder_name
```

First Open your super user which is root

In the above Command `user_name` is the name of user on which you want to set the ownership
`folder_name` is the folder which ownership you want to change

Comment: There is no need to do `sudo su` at all if you are already doing `sudo chown`.

Answer (score 2):

Command line: use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

Change to the directory that contain your files that you want changing. Use `sudo` in front of your command that changes permissions, the owner and group of those files.
You will be asked for your password and the command will execute as if you are root.

You could also do `sudo su` to enter root.

```
$ sudo su
[sudo] password for {username}: 
root@{host}:/home/{username}#
```

Then change to the directory that contain your files that you want changing.

Permission are changed with [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) Example: `chmod 755 somefile` would make it read, write, execute for your as the owner and read, execute for group and others.
User and group are changed with [`chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) Example: `chown alan:alan somefile` would make alan owner of somefile.

edit: after reading the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17144/how-can-i-become-the-owner-of-a-file-that-origins-from-another-pc-user) you posted I have a question! Did that topic not already answer your question? It talks about executing `gksu nautilus`. This option lets you use Nautilus as a root user. That would allow you to change access (see the picture in that topic).

Comment: Hi Rinzwind, thanks for your answer! As always I searched for the question before I posted mine, and ran across that one. It said to use `gksu nautilus` which was the first thing I tried prior to finding that question. But for some reason, I would change the permissions, and they would always reset, even as root. Weird!

Comment: Not weird! plain stupid ;) Might be a bug :X

Comment: I sure hope not! Either which way, I've stopped putting my wallpapers there, makes sense not to.