# how to create a user that has full rights under sftp in certain folder in ubuntu server

Tags: server, sftp, permissions

I just installed an Ubuntu 12.04 server in a dedicated box to host 2 sites I have, under one site there is a folder, lets call it /aaaaa and I want to create a user that have full rights under this certain folder via sftp.
the path of that folder is /var/www/domain.com/aaaaa

Comment: Do the procedure of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/40854/62483) help?

Comment: well thanx but this won't work.