# How to copy Folder as root to another hard drive?

Tags: root

Well, I am newbie on ubuntu and I want to copy file from ~/Documents/recoverd (all files from Recoverd Folder) to this drive /media/samerlol/7E7D1D0C55C0ABDF as a root user..
I tried some ways but all failed..

I used this command

```
samerlol@SamerLOL:~/Documents$ sudo cp recoverd/* /media/samerlol/7E7D1D0C55C0ABDF
```

but the result is this

```
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/3 Idiots (2009) 1080p BRRiP x264 AAC-AMEET6233 (T.M.R.G)'
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/A Gift of Fire- Social, Legal, and Ethical Issues for Computing Technology 4E [PDF]'
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/Celldweller Discography (1999 - 2013) {VB-320}'
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood {Ep 01-64 + Special} (Complete) [English Dubbed] 480p x264 ~ARIZONE'
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/Images'
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/Samer'
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/Videos'
cp: omitting directory 'recoverd/Who.Am.I No System is Safe 2014 BDRip 720p HEVC SUB ITA ENG-NAHOM'
```

It didn't copy directory, I want to copy Recoverd Folder and what it's inside to another harddrive...

Comment: Use `cp -r` to copy subdirectories and their contents. See `man cp`

Answer (score 2):

In order to copy directories you'll need the flag '-r':

From man cp:

```
   -R, -r, --recursive
          copy directories recursively
```

So  run something like:

```
 sudo cp -r recoverd/ /media/samerlol/7E7D1D0C55C0ABDF
```

Answer (score -2):

I found good way to do that by [Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40850/how-can-i-become-the-owner-of-a-file-folder-that-root-owns?rq=1)

GUI VERSION

Press ALT+F2 and type gksu nautilus This will turn you into an admin account using nautilus. Now go to those files and change the permissions/owner so your normal account can use them. This sometimes not work. At least for me they work and in another PC do not. Test and see.

The GUI version looks almost the same as Dash, except that instead of saying "Search" in the search bar it says "Run a command". Here is an image: