# testdisk unable to detect deleted folder

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

accidentally happened to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> a folder named `new` from my external HDD.  In my attempt to recover the lost data (very valuable to me) and after going through most of the previous such cases on Ask Ubuntu, resorted to using the intelligent `testdisk` recovery utility.

followed the [testdisk procedure](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/recovering-deleted-files-and-folders/2211), entered the advanced option and selected the list option as shown:

[image: phase_1]

Then maneuvered to the directory `Work`, from where the folder named `new` is deleted.

**It is here, that any deleted file/folder is highlighted.**

[image: phase_2]

In my case it fails to show the deleted folder `new`.

Notes:

- The external HD has been kept mounted and no system reboot performed yet.
- while doing `Deepsearch`, the system slows down real bad.

Comment: It's been a long while since I've used Testdisk but don't you have to go into the directory and restore the files? (ie, Press right arrow, select the files you want, and then shift+c to copy them into the working directory you were in before running testdisk.

Comment: Yes @Oli, you are right. As you can infer from image 2, I am currently present in the directory named 'work' and the folder 'new' was deleted from here. Ideally, testdisk detects the deleted files/folders and prints them in highlighted text for the user. In my case, the deleted folder 'new' is not been detected.

Comment: I mean go into the deleted directory. Get to where you are in picture two and press right.

Comment: @Oli I do not understand, but how can I go into the deleted directory 'new' if it is not detected, as seen picture two.

Comment: What happens if you press right?

Comment: it directs me into the folder on which I pressed right...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101793/discussion-between-kedar-and-oli).

Answer (score 0):

Happy to share with you the my research on how to recover deleted files on linux system.

**Two part solution**

1. Recovering the deleted files by [How To Recover Deleted Files In Linux [Beginner’s Guide]](https://itsfoss.com/recover-deleted-files-linux/)

*Make sure to select the `Undelete` option which displays the deleted files, instead of `list` option.*

2. Now that you have recovered the deleted files and copied it in the selected folder, the files' permission need to be changed from `root --> owner` by [How can I become the owner of a file/folder that root owns?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40850/how-can-i-become-the-owner-of-a-file-folder-that-root-owns)