# Recovering a SHIFT+DELETE folder

Tags: files, data-recovery, delete

I deleted a folder from work using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>, is there a way to recover it?

I know other questions exist, but they are old!

Comment: maybe this can help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193787/testdisk-unable-to-detect-deleted-folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover Deleted Files and Folders?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33800/how-to-recover-deleted-files-and-folders)

Comment: There is no undelete option!

Comment: @karel Ubuntu 20.04 has issues with the Desktop and does whatever it wants! My files where not deleted! However, in the process to recover the files i thought were deleted, i used TestDisk and it overflowed my hdd with data, leaving 0 bytes available. Now i cannot log into my system. But thanks for the help anyway!