# Setting directory file permissions in Ubuntu using chmod

Tags: chmod

whats the equivalent command of this (Fedora command) for Ubuntu:

```
chmod +a "www-data allow delete,write,append,file_inherit,directory_inherit" app/cache app/logs
```

When I try the above with Ubuntu (10.0.4 LTS), I get the error message:

```
chmod: invalid mode: `+a'
Try `chmod --help' for more information.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

chmod uses a series of numeric entries to set file permissions rather than strings. The ubuntu version of the command given would be

```
chmod 0755 app/cache app/logs
```

This should work assuming www-data is the owner. If not,

```
chown www-data.www-data app/cache app/logs
```

will change it so `www-data` owns the directories.

Detailed article: http://mdshaonimran.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/chmod-change-filefolder-permission-in-ubuntu/

Comment: [Generic warning against 777 permissions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/for-security-reasons-why-should-var-www-not-have-chmod-777/20110#20110).

Comment: Er, it looks like he's trying to add an ACL entry, not change the basic permissions.

Comment: @Random832 But apparently he was.

Answer (score 2):

The chmod +a actually sets an ACL that maintains the permissions when the directory is written to. The reason it's being used here is so that files and logs written to by the webserver, user www-data, have the same permissions as files written to by a user on the CLI.

It looks like he's pulling this from the Symfony 2 installation instructions.  Take a look at the updated documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

It states that the equivalent command in Ubuntu is

```
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:`whoami`:rwx app/cache app/logs
```