# How to mkdir -p -m 777 to all missing pathname directories?

Tags: command-line, cron

I'm putting a file in cron.hourly which needs to create a folder on the 1st time, and giving it access to an user so i don't need to use sudo if i want to remove all content in the folder. And in it makes folder usable also. `-m 777` doesn't work for missing folder when using `-p`

```
#!/bin/sh 
mkdir -m 777 -p 000Hourly/$(date +"%m-%d-%y_%T")
```

doesnt work: makes 000Hourly for admin

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir -m 777 000Hourly && mkdir -m 777 -p 000Hourly/$(date +"%m-%d-%y_%T")
```

gives on next hour error `mkdir: cannot create directory '000Hourly': File exists` and stops executing the rest of it.

This is what im trying to make so i need 777 so i could delete all folder when its too full.

```
#!/bin/sh
profiledir=/home/kangarooo/.mozilla/firefox/a2t42sie.default/
cd $profiledir;
mkdir -m 777 000Hourly ; mkdir -m 777 -p 000Hourly/$(date +"%m-%d-%y_%T") && cp -p sessionstore.js sessionstore.bak 000Hourly/$(date +"%m-%d-%y_%T")
exit 0
```

Comment: you should never set things to permissions of 777 - see this question for more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/for-security-reasons-why-should-var-www-not-have-chmod-777

Comment: i need that couse i need in my firefox folder to create this folder and i could delete it when theres too many copies of sessionrestore. Ok ill put full my code so ull know what im trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirname=000Hourly/$(date +"%m-%d-%y_%T") # Save the directory name for later access
user=bob   # Set to the username of the user who should have access.
group=bob  # Set to a group that should have access to the directory

mkdir -p "$dirname"
chown "$user:$group" "$dirname"
```

If only one user needs access, you're finished.

If more than one user needs to have access, create a group for everyone who needs access:

```
sudo groupadd mygroup
```

Read `man groupadd` for additional details, and change `mygroup` to whatever name you want (but it should begin with a lowercase letter or underscore and not include any spaces.

Then, add all necessary users to your new group, where `user1`, `user2`, and `user3` and the usernames to add. You can add as many as you want.:

```
for i in user1 user2 user3; do sudo usermod -aG mygroup "$i"; done
```

The new group memberships will take effect after the user logs out (or the machine is rebooted).

Now, modify your script above. Set `$group` to your new group, and add the following line:

```
chmod 775 "$dirname"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ -d 000Hourly ] || mkdir -m 777 000Hourly
mkdir -m 777 000Hourly/$(date +"%m-%d-%y_%T")
```