# alternative to chmod 777 in LAMP

Tags: lamp, chmod

Typically after installing LAMP I like to install phpmyadmin and be allowed to drop folders in `var/www/`.  I run `sudo chmod 777` only because the LAMP is on a LAN.  I was curious to know what is the better alternative to `sudo chmod 777`?  I do run as root but I can't seem to find anything that will be safe but still allow me to drop files or modify `apache2.conf`. My apologies if this has been asked before but I didn't see it from the searches.

**EDIT:**
I did learn how to use `gksudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and added `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` on the last line.  Rebooted Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart`.  I dont see any security issues with using gksudo.

Comment: Does this help: [For security reasons why should /var/www not have chmod 777?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/for-security-reasons-why-should-var-www-not-have-chmod-777)

Comment: Related (I guess): [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

Comment: `I was curious to know what is the better alternative to sudo chmod 777` ANY other method is better... Follow solution #1 from Lekensteyn in the link Aditya posted :-)