# How to create new files or modify existing files in a sym link?

Tags: apache2, php, lamp, symbolic-link

I am new to the LAMP environment.
I wanted to create files directly in my home directory instead of always copying it to /var/www.
I created a sym link using the following command :

```
ln -s /var/www ~/workspace/www
```

Now I can see a sym link www created in ~/workspace. I can access files in wwww. But, I can't modify existing files or create new files.

I know I am missing something. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably the folder `/var/www` belongs to `root` and you don't have permission to write there. So the symlink only enables you to read it not modify or create anything. You can always use `sudo` to modify those contents.

But do not change `/var/www` permission to gain access to it. This would be [a real bad idea](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777).

Here you can find [better solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/46371/127327) for your problem to access contents of `/var/www` without even using `sudo`.