# Samba Sharing on Mapped Share

Tags: networking, mount, permissions, samba, sharing

I am running Ubuntu Server 14.04 with the latest samba.  I have a Windows 2008 Storage Server NAS with a shared drive, that I mount in `fstab` in my Ubuntu.  Everything works great.

My dilemma is that I want to share the mapped drive from Ubuntu, not the little Nas device with Windows.  The share does publish, but nobody can write to it.  I've tried everything, including forcing permissions.  The Windows box has been setup with easy access (everyone) permissions for simplicity.  No matter what I do the system will not allow me to write files to it over the network.

I realize I could just have network users write directly to the NAS, which would work fine I suppose.  I'd rather control it all through the Linux file server though, and more or less hide the NAS from users.

Thought this would be simple through Linux/Samba, but apparently it can't be done through Samba.  The Windows box is obviously NTFS which could have something to do with it.

Worst case, I could setup an iSCSI connection between the NAS and Ubuntu.  I'd rather avoid that if possible though.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll answer my own question.  It is definitely possible.

The entry in `fstab` should be like this

```
//host/share /mnt/folder username=something,password=password,uid=65534,gid=65534,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,utf8, 0 0
```

I love Linux.  If you think it should be possible, there's usually a way.

---

**Editor's Note:**

OP used `file_mode=0777` and `dir_mode=0777`, but that is not encouraged, unless you know exactly what you wanted.

Check these questions

- [How will a server become vulnerable with chmod 777?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271596/how-will-a-server-become-vulnerable-with-chmod-777)
- [Is it a bad idea to CHMOD 777 all the files on your site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23161/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-chmod-777-all-the-files-on-your-site)
- [Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777)