# Read and write permissions for Owncloud www-data

Tags: permissions

I have owncloud running in Ubuntu server
I have enabled  external storage pointing to second hard drive in my machine and added a local storage

I can see the folder in owncloud but when I click on it I can see anything, empty

I need to fix the permissions (OC needs read and write permissions for www-data)

Run this command

sudo -u www-data ls -la /media/Test/Share/

I get

ls: cannot access /media/Test/Share/: Permission denied

How can I fix the permissions?

Answer (score 3):

To change the owner of a file (or folder) you use `chown` (ChangeOwner). You can specify a user and a group as owner. As in,

```
chown option user:group file/folder
```

In the situation you a describing, you could try the following, only change the group to www-data, so that the original owner isn't affected.

```
chown -R :www-data /media/Test/Share
```

Please notice the `:` before www-data...

To change the user and group owner of the folder,

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /media/Test/Share
```

-R option is used for "Recursive", it will also change the user & group of the folders contents (as in, any other directory or file that it holds).

Also check this other answer, [change-folder-permissions-and-ownership](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership)

This should do it.

Still, if the user or group don't have sufficient rights yet (read/write) you can use the chmod command for it.

I'll start with the warning...

Please, do not use the value 777 unless you know ***exactly*** what you are doing. Even then you should be wondering if it's worth it ;)

Read the following please: [Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777/20110#20110)

For instance, to give current user&group read/write rights on a file, but others none,

```
chmod 660 filename
```

See this article for more information on the values and a better explanation then I can give,

https://mdshaonimran.wordpress.com/2010/06/13/chmod-change-filefolder-permission-in-ubuntu/

Comment: I have tried all that and still I can't see folders and files inside local storage added to my owncloud.  When I run  sudo -u www-data ls -la /media/Test/Share/  I get still
ls: cannot access /media/Test/Share/: Permission denied

Comment: Not sure if you can use sudo in this manner with a system account. (not sure) As www-data probably does not have a shell specified for it.

Still, this should work, 

'sudo -u www-data /bin/bash -c ls -la /media/Test/Share'

Else/Also please post the current "ls -al" of the folder in question.

Comment: Change Test folder name for carlos
carlos@ubuntu:~$ sudo -u www-data /bin/bash -c ls -la /media/carlos/Share
Desktop    owncloud-8.0.0.tar.bz2  Release.key   your.website.net.pem
Documents  owncloud8.tar.bz2    Templates
Downloads  Pictures     Videos
Music    Public     your.website.net.key

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# cd /media/carlos/Share
root@ubuntu:/media/carlos/Share# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 25 19:49 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 3 root     root     4096 Mar 24 22:31 ..
drwxrwxrwx  3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 22 17:51 MyDrive
drwx------  4 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 25 19:17 .Trash-1000
root@ubuntu:/media/carlos/Share# ^C

Still I can't see files in the local storage in onwcloud

Comment: Got it to work now.  After I clean browser cache, folders just pop up

Thanks for all your help
Cheers