# Unable to open ubuntu in virtual box 6.1 after changing system permissions

Tags: virtualbox

I had virtual box previously installed and it worked fine until I created a new user and gave it permissions using:
`sudo chmod -R 777 /`
After that when I closed and reopened my virtual box I could not open Ubuntu.
I uninstalled and reinstalled virtual box.But this is what I am getting when I try to open Ubuntu.
[Virtual box ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzIZx.png)

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: ***why*** would you do `chmod 777` on the entire system?  **That will break the required permissions structure for many applications to function correctly**.  That's also NOT how you give users permissions to access things in Linux environments.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-shouldnt-var-www-have-chmod-777 https://askubuntu.com/questions/83/how-do-file-permissions-work  Fixing a recursive chmod 777 is near impossible, you'd have better luck reinstalling the VM.

Comment: I didn't know what I was doing to be honest.I just stumbled upon this command and used it.And now I don't how to fix it.I did reinstall it but its still not working.

Comment: Going forward, it's best not to execute commands you don't understand, especially if they involve sudo.

Comment: Yes I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled it again and it works now.