# 'chmod u+x' versus 'chmod +x'

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, chmod

What is the difference between `chmod u+x` and just `chmod +x`?  I have seen a ton of tutorials that say to use `u+x` to make scripts executable.  However, omitting the `u` doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

The man page of `chmod` covers that.

- *u* stands for user.
- *g* stands for group.
- *o* stands for others.
- *a* stands for all.

That means that `chmod u+x somefile` will grant only the owner of that file execution permissions whereas `chmod +x somefile` is the same as `chmod a+x somefile`.

[The chmod man page says:](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod)

> The format of a symbolic mode is
>   `[ugoa...][[+-=][rwxXstugo...]...][,...]`.
>   Multiple symbolic operations can be
>   given, separated by commas.
>
> A combination of the letters 'ugoa'
>   controls which users' access to the
>   file will be changed: the user who
>   owns it (u), other users in the file's
>   group (g), other users not in the
>   file's group (o), or all users (a). If
>   none of these are given, the effect is
>   as if 'a' were given, but bits that
>   are set in the umask are not affected.

Comment: I have a little question, what is the difference between a+x and let's say 111. It makes both executable

Comment: That is because 1 is the octal notation which stands for the execute permission. 111 means executable for user, group and other.

Comment: Great clean answer

Comment: The umask effect is important, making `chmod +x file` different from `chmod a+x file` - see Ravexina's answer for details.

Answer (score 26):

#### Requirements

First of all I suggest you to read these questions and the answers linked below:

- [What is the difference between “chmod +x” and “chmod 755”?](https://askubuntu.com/a/932719/264781)
- [What is “umask” and how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work)

It helps you understand all the necessary parts you need to know.

---

#### Short version

- `chmod +x` is equal to `chmod ugo+x` (Based on `umask` value)
- `chmod a+x` is equal to `chmod ugo+x` (Without considering `umask` value)

---

#### Explanation

The result of `chmod a+x` is to set the executable bit for everyone (Owner, Group, Others), easy right?

However with `chmod +x` it's a little bit tricky, it says use `umask` value and based on that value add the `x` to everyone that is allowed.

So if the `umask` of my environment is `0002`:

```
$ umask
0002
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx
```

It's going to add `x` to user (owner), group and others, in this situation (which is the default situation for most systems) it's exactly like `chmod ugo+x` or the same as `chmod a+x`, or in a more verbose form:

```
chmod u+x,g+x,o+x
```

Can you spot the connection between `chmod u+x,g+x,o+x` and the output of `umask -S`?

Now let’s change the `umask` of the current shell to `0003`:

```
$ umask 0003
$ umask
0003
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rwx,o=r
```

As you can see now only owner and group are going to get the executable bit and not the others. It means `chmod +x` is now equal to `chmod u+x,g+x` or `chmod ug+x`.

---

#### Question time!

What happens if I run `chmod +w` on a file after setting `umask` to `0003`?

Same as before, it only affects `user` and `group` of the file because 3 also removes the write permission (2).

---

#### Bonus

It has the same effect when you are removing a bit like `chmod -w`:

```
$ mkdir test
$ stat -c %A test
drwxrwxr-x
```

```
$ umask
0002
```

```
$ chmod +w test
$ stat -c %A test
drwxrwxr-x
```

```
$ chmod a+w test
$ stat -c %A test
drwxrwxrwx
```

```
$ chmod -w test
chmod: test/: new permissions are r-xr-xrwx, not r-xr-xr-x
```

```
$ stat -c %A test
dr-xr-xrwx
```

Answer (score 23):

Just doing `+x` will apply it to all flags: [u]ser, [g]roup, [o]thers.

Type [`man chmod`](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) for more information.

Comment: I promise I checked the manual first but didn't see it since I skipped the description and jumped down to the options. I see them now though :-)

Answer (score 11):

`chmod u+x` will made the file executable for your user (it will only add it for your user, though it may be already executable by the group owner, or "other").

`chmod +x` or `chmod a+x` ('all plus executable bit') makes the file executable by everyone.

If you do this to a directory, it makes the directory searchable, instead.  I.e., you can list the contents of a directory that you have +x permission on.

Comment: @AnkitGupta I'm not sure what you're saying.  My comment wasn't intended to fix a problem in a different Q&A.  Try asking for clarification to answers there instead.  Edit your question to say what you've tried.  Show the output.

Answer (score 2):

- `chmod u+x file` means add the executable bit to the owner of the file while ignoring the `umask` (Your mod will be set, no question).
- `chmod +x file` means add the executable bit to the owner, group and others while considering the `umask` (First check with `umask` then apply the mods, it might have different effects based on umask's value ).

---

let's create two files:

```
$ touch file1 file2
$ ls -l file1 file2
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ravexina ravexina 0 Aug  5 01:45 file1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ravexina ravexina 0 Aug  5 01:45 file2
```

Now I set the `umask` to "111" to remove executable bits: `umask 111`.

```
$ chmod u+x file1
$ chmod  +x file2
```

```
$ ls -l file1 file2
-rwxrw-rw- 1 ravexina ravexina 0 Aug  5 01:47 file1
-rw-rw-rw- 1 ravexina ravexina 0 Aug  5 01:47 file2
```

As you can see the `chmod` ignored the `umask` and the file1 got executable bit for its owner however the second one did nothing because it's considering umask's value.