# Hide multiple files at once with shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, rename

I'm trying to hide some files with some command, I tried the rm command, but it did not work and also tried to rename but did not understand how it works.
The files that I want to hide have spaces in their names and I just want to put the dot in front of the names to let them hidden.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post the command you used or an example of the files. In general, hiding the files is not considered to be overly secure. I suggest you use unique login for each user. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/46501/why-can-other-users-see-the-files-in-my-home-folder . If that is not sufficient, honestly I suggest you use encryption.

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the terminal

```
    $ for i in *
    > do
    > mv "$i" ".$i"
    > done
```

It hides all the files in the current directory. I hope that's what you're looking for.
EDIT: Added the quotes around `$i`.

Comment: That will not work for files with spaces. You would need to quote the variable. Also the "*" is very non-specific. find is, IMO, a better tool. If all the files are in a single directory, why not just hide the directory?

Comment: It worked!. I put quotes in the variables "$i" ".$i" and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @PattersonSilva If an answer solves your problem, please accept it as the correct one by clicking the little tick mark next to the answer.

Comment: `*` is just an example. One could be more specific as well with something like `*.py` or you know, whatever criteria one has for hiding the files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mmv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/mln.1.html):

```
mmv -v "*" ".#1"
```

Simple and to the point!

To un-hide them back:

```
mmv -v ".*" "#1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rename 's/^/./' file1.txt 'file with spaces' 'third file.mkd'
```

You can of course use globs. The following will add a dot to the beginning of every file that ends with `.txt`:

```
rename 's/^/./' *.txt
```

Or you could hide every file beginning with `foo` and ending with `.mkd`:

```
rename 's/^/./' foo*.mkd
```

`rename` is using a substitute command: `s/foo/bar/` replaces the first `foo` with `bar`. Instead of `foo`, you can also use a regular expression, and in regexes `^` means 'the beginning of the line'. So `s/^/./` tells `rename` to 'replace the beginning of the line with a `.`'. That is: it places the dot *before* the first character.

You can also use the `-n` option to do a 'test run' -- with that, `rename` will not actually rename the files, but will list all the files that it *would have* changed, were you not using the `-n` flag.

```
rename -n 's/^/./' *.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

To quickly hide all files of the current directory from display in Nautilus:

```
ls * > .hidden
```

This will create a list of hidden files in the file `.hidden` within the current directory. It will of course not hide these files on the command line, and if we chose to display hidden files from Nautilus they will show up again (as will `.` files).

To only hide a subset of files use appropriate wildcards, or edit the `.hidden` file with an editor.

To show all files again, just remove the `.hidden` file.

Answer (score 0):

My prefered method is using "nautilus-hide" in "Nautilus-Actions-Extra" package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions-extra nautilus-hide
nautilus -q
```

After selecting files/folders in Nautilus, choose (Un)Hide > Hide from the context menu.

This creates a file named ".hidden" containing a list of files/folders to be hidden.