# Possible weakness in www-data Permission?

Tags: server, 20.04, permissions, apache2, security

today I was testing something on my VPS and realized the "www-data" user has read access into Home folders and into System internal folders as well which would give an possible Attacker, the ability to gather Information outside of the /var/www directory e.g. RSA_Keys or batch Files in Home Directory's.

First I thought I faulted my File Permissions or something but I could reproduce this behavior on an fresh installed Virtual Machine.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, with all Updates applied
Webserver: Apache2 with standard config

How did I test: `sudo -u www-data bash` --> `nano /home/user/stuff.txt` or `nano /folder/rsa.pem`

Is this an expected Behavior? Do I miss something?
And how can I deny the www-data User access to specific folders?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is by design. You can easily restrict access, check https://askubuntu.com/questions/46501/why-can-other-users-see-the-files-in-my-home-folder. And if you follow Ubuntu Server guide, you [will be told](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-users).

Comment: Btw: Ubuntu > 21.04 [defaults to private user `$HOME` directories](https://ubuntu.com/blog/private-home-directories-for-ubuntu-21-04).

Answer (score 0):

Golbally-readable /home directories is expected behavior in Ubuntu 20.10 and earlier releases.

The behavior has been changed in 21.04 and newer releases; /home directories are no longer globally readable.

- New installs of 21.04 and newer get the new behavior.
- New installs of 20.04 and older get the old behavior
- Release upgrades do NOT change the behavior. If you release-upgrade from 20.04 to, say, 22.04, your /home dir will remain globally-readable

Back in the day, you *wanted* folks to be able to read (not write) to files in your directory. That's one way that you shared information on a multi-user system. Of course, you also knew better than to keep private data on a multi-user system.

From a security standpoint, it's still true: Servers should be treated as multi-user systems. Don't keep sensitive private documents 1) Unencrypted, and 2) On the same filesystem as a public webserver.