# Permissions issue when trying to save file to /var/www

Tags: 12.04, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to avoid using sudo when working in /var/www?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46331/how-to-avoid-using-sudo-when-working-in-var-www)

I have install PHP from this article on my ubuntu computer

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/installing-php5-and-apache-on-ubuntu/

now when I tried to save a simply php file I am unable to do that. I have no access to that folder var/www

$ chmod +x /var

chmod: changing permissions of `/var': Operation not permitted

I am not sure what this command do. can someone let me know how to get it worked then I can save file from any software I use.

I just have install php and it's work fine and this post is about giving 'var/www' permission that I can save the file their.

Thanks

---

Now after a restart my computer I got my permission worked.

Comment: The chmod command allows you the change the rights you, your group and others have upon a particular file. For instance the command you have typed there attempts to make the /var folder executable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The folder /var/www needs root permission to change its rights. Why not try:

```
sudo chmod +x /var
```

If that is not working for you, then try to modify only the **www** folder which seems to be of special interest to you, like this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thanks, but I still found no changes. still got a same problem. After doing this I can see the time in last changed. please help !

Comment: Really, I can not understand why you still have the issue? Double checked my solution on my machine and it works great.

Comment: Sorry please look at http://postimage.org/image/5yub08wn3/18e4a811/ and http://postimage.org/image/9896q6h55/725e5be9/

Comment: From the images you posted, I can see that the command was successful as to what it was assigned to do: make the folder executable. If you have any other issues, then you might have to run this command: sudo chmod 777 /var

Comment: -1 abuse of chmod. `/var` is a directory which already has the descend (execute) bit set, so the first command does not make sense (neither did the one from the OP make sense). `chmod 777` is the worst thing you can do, especially on a public-faced directory like `/var/www`.

Comment: Sure it is, I do not disagree with you. I was just advising chmod 777 as diagnostics, to see if he could solve his problem. I never leave files or folders with chmod 777.

Comment: @NlightNfotis It's worked now after a restart. I really don't know how to operate Linux.

Comment: This is old as all hell, but for anyone coming in late make sure to remove those permissions if you're done diagnosing. Currently I set up (On Arch but the principle applies, `/var/www/` on Ubuntu) a `/srv/http/` directory in my `~/Documents/` folder so I can `sudo cp -R ~/srv/http/* /srv/http/` to publicize my updates; I recommend choosing security of your server, if it is public, over practicality. You can, however, run your text editor with sudo or gksudo: `gksudo gedit /var/www/index.php` (For the Arch buddies out there, you'll have to `sudo pacman -S gksu`).

Answer (score 6):

If you are using it for development just change the owner of /var/www folder to your username.

```
sudo chown username:username -R /var/www
```

make sure to change the "username" word from the above command to yours.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Remember to change both username text. My username is isuru so it should be sudo chown isuru:isuru -R /var/www

Answer (score 2):

Since the directory is owned by root, you will not be able save a php file with any editor without running with gksu as root. So, I suggest two simple ways to fix this:

`sudo cp /path/to/file.php /var/www/`

(or)

Run the editor as root using `gksu` and save the file at `/var/www/`

Also, for a glitch free execution of the php file, make sure the file has 755 permissions.
Hope I've been of some help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo chmod +x /var` is used to add/remove permissions to/from the specified file/folder.

- parameter `+` used to add permissions
- parameter `-` used to remove permissions
- parameter `r` mean read permission, `w` is write and `x` is execute.

Example:

```
sudo chmod -r -w +x /var/www
```

remove read permission, remove write permission and give execute permission to `/var/www` folder for all users and group.

You can simply run `gksu nautilus` and go to the `/var/www` directory, then right-click on it. Choose *Properties*, then go to the permission tab where you can change permissions of that folder/file.

Comment: `chmod` is also affected by [umask](http://askubuntu.com/q/44542/6969). With stricter umasks (e.g. 777), the `chmod` story here does not apply.