# Why does umask 077 not allow the user to execute files/directories?

Tags: umask

I'm using umask 077 ."Other" and "group" do not have any rights, but the user  can't execute files/directories.
Why does umask 077 not allow the owner to execute files/directories?

Answer (score 8):

The *umask* value will be used to appropriately modify the default *fmask* for file permissions (base permission 0666) and *dmask* for directory/folder permissions (base permission 0777).

The effective *fmask* and *dmask* values will be calculated by deducting the *umask* value (Octal calculations).

So a *umask* 0022 would result in *fmask* to get a value 0644 (i.e. 0666 - 0022) while *dmask* would be 0755 (i.e. 0777 - 0022).

The *umask* 0077 prevent files from being created with any access not only to the world (indicated by the ultimate octal digit) but also your **group members** (indicated by the penultimate octal digit).

#### Reference:

- [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)

Comment: the more i read this, the more i'm not understand it. Is there any explanation for newbie guy who only want to do small changes without knowing deep?

Answer (score 7):

When you use a `umask` of 077 **only** the user has read, write and execute permissions. The user definitely will be able to open ('execute') directories (see more on why directories have to be executable [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276690/why-does-chmod-644-make-directories-inaccessible/276858#276858)). However, files must always be made executable by entering `chmod u+x myfile`; they are never automatically executable. Some more useful information on `umask` is given in this answer:

- [What is "umask" and how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work)

The likely possibility for your problems is that you have perhaps entered the value slightly incorrectly, which has resulted in a different umask, or that the value has not been permanently set. If you enter `umask 077` in the terminal it will only hold good for that session of the terminal; to make it permanent for your user simply add `umask 077` to your `~/.profile`. The system default setting for `umask` is in `/etc/login.defs`; it *used* to be in `/etc/profile`. See also the manpage for `pam_umask`, which is a pam module that handles the assignment of `umask`.

The following examples are from a successful setting of `umask 077`:

1) *For folder creation*: `mkdir doc` checked with `stat doc` gave the correct permissions and an 'executable' folder:

```
File: `doc'
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 6425268     Links: 2
Access: (0700/drwx------)  Uid: ( 1000/    mike)   Gid: ( 1000/    mike)
Access: 2012-09-12 11:33:01.236675420 +0100
Modify: 2012-09-12 11:33:01.236675420 +0100
Change: 2012-09-12 11:33:01.236675420 +0100
 Birth: -
```

2) *For file creation*: `touch new` checked with `stat new` gave the correct permissions; the file is only made executable when you use `chmod +x`:

```
File: `new'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 6303902     Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: ( 1000/    mike)   Gid: ( 1000/    mike)
Access: 2012-09-12 11:34:58.272676270 +0100
Modify: 2012-09-12 11:34:58.272676270 +0100
Change: 2012-09-12 11:34:58.272676270 +0100
```

A `umask` of 077 will give the permissions shown, but if you still have problems with permissions after setting `umask 077` properly (as discussed further above) we can look into it further.