# Permissions denied to owner, although it is set to 666 in .ssh directory

Tags: permissions, ssh, chmod

I recently messed around with the .ssh directory. Made some permission changes, I think and now it won't let me access it anymore. I can access it as the root user (sudo -i) but not as user1

I get permission denied when listing or cding into .ssh even though it shows the files

```
ls: cannot access /home/user1/.ssh/amazon.pem: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/user1/.ssh/known_hosts: Permission denied
ls: cannot access /home/user1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? amazon.pem
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? id_rsa.pub
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? known_hosts
```

Logging in as root and ls gives following results

```
# ls -l /home/user1/ -a |grep ssh
drw-rw-rw-  2 user1 user1 4096 Aug 27 15:45 .ssh
```

Even the files inside are .ssh are owned by user1:user1 and chm

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user1 user1 1692 Aug 27 15:45 amazon.pem
-rw-rw-rw- 1 user1 user1 1675 Aug 25 20:01 id_rsa
```

Comment: See [Why does chmod 644 make directories inaccessible?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276690/why-does-chmod-644-make-directories-inaccessible). AFAIK the correct permissions for the `~/.ssh` directory is `700` (`drwx------`).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Steeldriver is right. On directory you need also `x` access flag to be able to list files inside.

Fixing the directory using `chmod 700 ~/.ssh` should help you to get into this (correct) state:

```
$ ls -ld ~/.ssh
drwx------. 2 user user 4096 Aug 26 10:37 /home/user/.ssh
```

Also you should fix your keys using `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub` to get this:

```
$ ls -l ~/.ssh/
-rw-------. 1 user user  1766 Mar  7  2014 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--. 1 user user   415 Mar  7  2014 id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: I managed to fix this before itself, by copying it somewhere else and then copying it back

Answer (score -2):

When you run command **ls -l** on any directory the first column is the permission column which is interpreted as follows:

1-------------**2     3     4**-------*5     6     7*-------8     9     10

(TYPE)----**(user)**-----*(group)*----(others)

TYPE : If **'-'**, it is a file. If **'d'** it is a directory.

Permissions: **read: 4, write: 2, execute: 1**

So for read, write and execute your permissions will be **7** in user group.

You can use

```
sudo chmod 7 6 6 file_name
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R u+x /home/somesh/.ssh
```

**-R** – this modifies the permission of the parent folder and the child objects within

Comment: I don't understand the TYPE part; also `chmod 700 file_name` and `chmod u+x file_name` do two completely different things. The first one sets the permissions to `rwx/---/---`, the second one just sets the `x` bit for the owner (and starting from `666` it will change the file to `766`, not to `700`).

Comment: @kos, s/he means the first field in the string indicates the type of file entry. A `-` character means it's a "normal" file. A `d` means it is a directory. There are others, too, like `c`, `l` (for symbolic link), `s`, and even more for other OSes.

Comment: @Josh Yep, the layout confused me.