# How to set up default permissions for files

Tags: permissions

Does anyone know how to set the default permissions if a user makes a new file, the file will have -rwxrw-r—permission.

Comment: Read everything about default file permissions in `man umask`.

Comment: but @Jos what `umask` setting adds `x` bit???

Comment: @Zanna None. This is a Unix-wide security precaution: no file ever created is automatically executable. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/186747/why-umask-077-does-not-allow-user-to-execute-files-directories

Comment: so the answer is, it can't be done... @Jos

Comment: It can't be set as the default, no.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** As some users have commented, automatically creating files with executable permissions breaks a significant part of the Linux security model.

That said there is a way to achieve what you want, on the command line and to limit which users can do this.

You could write a function to create the file and modify the permissions at the same time. This function should be added to each users `.bashrc` file. This file can be found at `/home/username/.bashrc`.

Here's an example to make a function called createafile, 
The lines to add would be:

```
createafile() {
if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
  echo "Cannot create a file with no name!"
  return 1
elif [[ -e $1 ]]
  echo "That file already exists!"
  return 1
elif [[ $2 = -* ]]; then
  echo "Permissions must not start with a '-'!"
  return 1
fi
touch $1
if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
  perms=764
else
  perms=$2
fi
chmod $perms $1
}
```

Once this is written into a user's `.bashrc` file, they must log out and back in before it can be used. The function can be called on the command line like so.

```
createafile newfile.txt
```

Which will create the file with your default octal permissions of 764, or `-rwxrw-r--`. Alternatively if you want to specify a different permission mode you can enter this in any recognised format for the `chmod` command. So to make a file with read/write permission for everyone

```
createafile anotherfile.txt 555
```

or

```
createafile anotherfile.txt a+rw
```

This function will complain and exit if the file already exists, or if you don't enter a filename. The function will not work if the user doesn't have the appropriate directory permissions to write the file or change permissions.

There's a line in the function that stops users entering a `chmod` option accidentally. This does mean that you can't use the permission removal functionality of `chmod` where the permissions start with a `-` character.

Comment: It's my first `.bashrc` function! Glad you like it ^_^. I'm a bit worried about the possibility of passing a `chmod` option accidentally but couldn't work out the regex to see is there's a dash at the start of line.

Comment: Good catch. `-R` is pretty useful, but there are a lot of errors made by newer users, when they blitz `/usr/bin` or come other necessary directory with wrong perms!

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying, and that's generally how I end up using it. It's normally in `/var/www/html for web stuff, but you do always end up fixing directory perms afterwards. That gives me an idea for another function!

Comment: Did this answer help at all @ForestAmp ?