# Problem with umask

Tags: permissions, umask

I put the following mask: "umask u=rw, g=x. After that I create a file on the desktop, but for some reason there are no execution rights for the group. To give the group execution rights is obtained through chmod. Is there really no way to give permissions through umask?

Comment: `umask` can only *deduct* bits - see for example [Why does umask 077 not allow the user to execute files/directories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186747/why-does-umask-077-not-allow-the-user-to-execute-files-directories)