# Setting Default Permissions

Tags: permissions

I've read a lot of solutions for something like this, but nothing seems to work quite right for me. I have a shared development box used for a few projects that require such a thing and I'd like to configure it so that files created by users in the `/opt/dev` directory:

- Are owned by `<username>:developers`
- Have permissions set to `774` (files)
- Have permissions set to `775` (directories)

All developer users have their primary group set to `developers` so the first requirement has been pretty solid. What's a lot less solid is the actual permissions. They just aren't being set consistently the way we need them to get set and I haven't found the right solution.

I do have the sticky bit set (`g+s`) based on something else I read at some point, but that wouldn't *seem* to be particularly useful since all users are in the same primary group.

I also have the default `umask` set to `002` in `/etc/login.defs`. I thought that would kind of cover it, that doesn't seem to be the case.

I'd really appreciate any advice about how to get everything lined up properly. I feel like I'm constantly in there adjusting a file here and a directory there just so people can do their work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, for point 1, the solution is quite easy:

```
chgrp developers /opt/dev
```

For points 2 and 3, I suppose you'll need `ACL`. So, the first thing to do is to edit `/etc/fstab` to give the option `acl` to the mountpoint of `/opt/dev`. If `/opt/dev` is not on a separate partition you'll need to enable `ACL` for the whole root filesystem.

Then you'll have to follow [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1315/18904).

```
chmod g+s /opt/dev
```

should be equivalent to `chgrp developers /opt/dev` (and doesn't set the `sticky` bit, `s` sets the `suid` bit).

Then proceed with `setfacl`:

```
setfacl -d -m g::rwx /opt/dev  //set group to rwx default 
setfacl -d -m o::rx /opt/dev   //set other
```

to set advanced permission criteria for files and directories. To be honest, I couldn't find a way to set separate file and directory permissions, but I'm pretty sure it's doable. You can try [this tutorial](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/ACL/linux-acl.html#scenario) to have more information about the topic.

Comment: Thanks, @Avio. I'll try the ACL path, but for my own edification, if I have the "global default" UMASK set to 022, why doesn't that accomplish this purpose? I know folks _could_ override, but they aren't in my case. Most are accessing this area via Samba. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You probably don't have the `umask` set to `022` as I don't. The value in `/etc/login.defs` is probably overwritten during boot. Reading [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/44548/63606), if you type `umask` at the terminal, you'll see that you have only `0002`. That means that only the `write` permission for `others` is forbidden (during the creation of files). And so it is. Try it in `/tmp` with some `touch` and a few `mkdir`, and you should see it.