# /opt folder missing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, directory, eclipse

I'm trying to install Eclipse "by the book" in /opt, but when trying to access /opt, it seems that /opt directory doesn't exist in Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ cd /opt/
bash: cd: /opt/: No such file or directory
$ ls -a /
.   bin   cdrom  etc   initrd.img      lib    lost+found  mnt   root  sbin  sys  usr  vmlinuz
..  boot  dev    home  initrd.img.old  lib64  media       proc  run   srv   tmp  var  vmlinuz.old
```

Why is the /opt folder missing? How to re-create one if applicable & what are the permissions to apply?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Directory `/opt` is optional. It is not being used for anything in the standard Ubuntu distro so somebody decided not to create one.

Not a big deal. Just create it with `sudo mkdir /opt`

**Edit**

As suggested by `waltinator` a better command would be `mkdir --mode=755 /opt`

Comment: +1 While `sudo mkdir --mode=755 /opt` has the advantages of being very self-documenting and working the same way on another OS or on an Ubuntu system with unusual settings, I think the simpler `sudo mkdir /opt` should be considered equally fine. The default `umask` for root (as revealed by `sudo -s umask`) is 0022, so a directory created by running `mkdir` as root should have permissions 0755. See the answers at [What is “umask” and how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work) for details.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest `mkdir --mode=755 /opt`. Read/Write/Search for Owner (`root:root`), Read/Search for Group and Other. Allows `root` to create files/directories, allows anybody else to search and descend the directory tree under `/opt` (depending on lower nodes permissions)