# Creating files when "sudoed" messes up permissions and users

Tags: command-line, 16.04, permissions, sudo, files

I have some trouble installing some packages I compiled from source. Everything seems to work fine, until I try to actually use the files installed in a global place.

It turns out the permisions and users/groups of the newly created files are all messed up. It is very easy for me to replicate with a simple directory and file creation commands:

```
$ sudo mkdir /usr/local/bar
$ sudo touch /usr/local/bar/foo
$ ls -l /usr/local
total 11M
drwxr--r--  2 root root 4,0K jul 24 23:56 bar/
[...]
$ ls -l /usr/local/bar/
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bar/foo': Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? foo
$ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bar/
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 jul 24 23:56 foo
```

As seen by the example above, the created directory looks fine initially, but when looking inside it the user, group and everything else for the files is totally messed up. They do look fine when looking at it from the superuser perspective with `sudo`.

Using `chown` or `chmod` doesn't matter, as long as I use `sudo` whatever I do results in the same problem.

My `/etc/sudoers` file (without comments):

```
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

myusername  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

It should all be default, except for the last line which I added to not have to write the password every time.

I have a fully up-to-date 16.04 installation.

Could it be something wrong with my installation? Something wrong with `sudo` or how I use it? Anything else?

---

Output of `umask -S` as requested:

```
$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=r,o=r
$ sudo bash -c "umask -S"
u=rwx,g=r,o=r
```

And

```
$ grep '^UMASK\|^USERGROUPS_ENAB' /etc/login.defs
UMASK       033
USERGROUPS_ENAB no
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `umask -S` and `sudo bash -c "umask -S"` please?

Comment: @ByteCommander Added.

Comment: There is the problem. Now I also need the output of `grep '^UMASK\|^USERGROUPS_ENAB' /etc/login.defs ` please and I'll write an answer for you :)

Comment: @ByteCommander Added that too.

Comment: Thanks, I'm writing. Do you have an idea why `USERGROUPS_ENAB` is `no` and `UMASK` is `033` instead of the default `022`? Did you change that manually?

Comment: @ByteCommander I don't remember setting that... I do remember changing the UMASK though.

Comment: And why did you change `UMASK`? Do you need the changes? Because the problem here is that you do not give execution permissions by default, but those are needed to browse a directory. Without that, you are not able to list new directories' contents.

Comment: @ByteCommander Doh! I *know* that! Write up your asnwer and I'll vote it up and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem on your system is that your `umask` settings are a bit strange/messed up.

For general information about `umask` please refer to [What is "umask" and how does it work?](https://askubuntu.com/q/44542/367990)
In short we can say that the `umask` defines the default permission set for new files. It is configured in `/etc/login.defs`.

The default value for `umask` is `022` which results in default permissions for new files to be `rwxr-xr-x` (owner: full access, group: read/execute, world: read/execute).

You have changed this setting to `033` which results in default permissions to be `rwxr--r--`, i.e. no execute permissions for group and others.

The problem we're facing here when removing execute permissions from a directory is that it becomes no longer browsable. You need the execute permission to list a directory's contents. Because the newly generated directories have execution for everybody but their owner declined, only the owner user (here root) can list the directory contents by default.

---

You have two options:

- Keep the `umask` and manually add execution permissions for others using `chmod +x` on all directories where you need them.

  This is a lot of work and you will likely forget it every now and then. Only do this if you have a good reason for a non-default `umask`.
- Reset the `umask` back to its default `022`.

  To do this, open the file `/etc/login.defs` with your favourite text editor as root, e.g. using `sudo nano /etc/login.defs`.

  Search for this line:

  ```
  UNAME       033
  ```

  And replace it with the default settings again:

  ```
  UNAME       022
  ```

---

Additionally I have also seen that you have `USERGROUPS_ENAB` set to `no`, but its default is `yes`. This setting does not only make the `umask` group permissions equal to the owner permissions for non-root users, but also causes automatic generation (and deletion, if no longer needed) of users' primary groups (same name and ID as user).

I would personally recommend to reset that line to its defaults as well, unless you have a reason not to do that.

Therefore search the line

```
USERGROUPS_ENAB no
```

and replace it with

```
USERGROUPS_ENAB yes
```

Comment: I added a paragraph because I'm a bit confused why you have set `USERGROUPS_ENAB no`. I would personally recommend to reset it back to "yes", but that is not directly related with the problem described in the question.