# Modify permissions to -rwxr-xr-x

Tags: permissions, chmod

I need some help with a homework problem to modify a file's permissions. It wants it to be `-rwxr-xr-x`? Not sure how to make the user permissions. Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Lets analyze your homework: `-rwxr-xr-x`, break them into three parts `-rwx|r-x|r-x`:

1. `rwx`: read, write and execute for user or owner
2. `r-x`: read, no write, and execute for group members
3. `r-x`: same as in `2` but this time for every other person aka `others`.

No you will need to run the command using the change permission program `chmod` like so:

```
chmod 755 filename
```

Explained:

- change the permission to:

  ```
  - user: 7 => r(4), w(2), x(1)
  - group: 5 => r(4), -, x(1)
  - others: r(4), -, x(1)
  ```

Now you have to own that file or folder to do this or be in the sudo group.

Comment: Also the `sudo` is only needed for files you don't own, which is probably not the case as part of a homework.

Comment: Noted @Zanna and ByteCommander

Comment: It worked, just got a little confused on the user's permission, but understand clearly now, Thanks everybody for your help.

Answer (score 14):

There's also a more "talkative" version to set permissions:

```
 chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o=rx filename
```

This means:

- give the user (`u=`) `rwx` permissions, and
- give the group (`g=`) `rx` permissions, and
- give others (`o=`) `rx` permissions.

You can leave out the parts that you do not want to change, e.g.:

```
 chmod u=rwx filename
```

will set the user's permissions and leave the others as they are.

You can even "add" or "substract" permissions:

```
 chmod g-x filename
```

will remove the group's `x` permission, and

```
chmod o+w filename
```

will add write permission for others.

To set SUID, SGID, and sticky bit use the `s` and `t` permissions:

- `chmod u+s filename` -- sets SUID
- `chmod g+s filename` -- sets SGID
- `chmod a+t filename` -- sets sticky bit (`a` means "all", i.e. `u` and `g` and `o`)

Comment: So which method would this be, SGUID, SGID or sticky bit? How would I do the others using this method?

Comment: @Rich I updated my answer.

Comment: But sticky bit is only for directories, can it be used for text files? Would these the same commands for fedora?

Comment: Good catch. I forgot that. Linux ignores the sticky bit for files, but [other OSes honor it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit#Usage). And yes, the commands work an any Unixy OS.

Comment: @Rich the horse has bolted, but if you're using fedora, you shouldn't be asking questions here on Ask Ubuntu...

Comment: Sorry just wanted to see if anybody knew, but got my answer. Sorry everybody and thanks for your help.

Comment: So first I set the file to 755, then change it to the type of permissions? Like for ex. I made 3 files: $chmod 755 file (1)(2)(3)  then use the chmod u+s file1, chmod g+s file 2, chmod a+t file 3? Is this right?

Comment: @Rich please don't ask follow-up questions in comments on an answer outside the scope of the original question. You should post a new question about this, and if you're using fedora, you should post it on [unix.se] and say what OS you are working on

Answer (score 6):

**Obligatory Preamble**

Modifying permissions of important files and directories in your system can [break things badly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43621/what-if-i-accidentally-run-command-chmod-r-on-system-directories-etc). If you would find it inconvenient to have to reinstall your system or retrieve data from a live session, make sure you experiment with permissions and ownership safely. While you're learning your way around the filesystem and basic commands, you should ***avoid** running `chmod` and `chown` with `sudo` or in a root shell*. That way, a permission error will let you know that you might be doing something risky and you should check the command again.

We change file permissions with `chmod`. This command has a recursive flag `-R`. This flag is often used unnecessarily, and it is rarely useful, because we don't usually want directories to have the same permissions as the files inside them. Directories need execute permission to be entered, so aren't useful without it, while files only need execute permission if they are programs. Without the `-R` flag, `chmod` can do only limited and repairable damage, but with `-R` you can make a terrible mess of your system in a single command. If you are using `-R`, consider whether you really need it, and check the file path for typos.

---

The mode you have been asked to give the file is a common one

```
-rwxr-xr-x
```

The leading dash indicates that this is a regular file. The `x` bits  in three places indicate that it needs to be executable by any user. So, this mode is appropriate for programs that anyone can execute. Most programs on your system have this mode, as you can see by examining the files in `/usr/bin`, `/bin` and so on (I explain how to examine permissions later in this answer). It's important for security that only the owner, root, can write to (modify) these files, so the programs you run can't be accidentally (or otherwise) changed by users without root privileges.

As pointed out in [George Udosen's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027005/527764) the permission bits are set separately for user (the owner of the file), group, and others. This is explained, for example, in [our tag wiki for `chmod`](https://askubuntu.com/tags/chmod/info) and in many other places on the internet, and even on your system; you can read about it by running `man chmod`. You have been asked to make the file readable, writeable and executable by its owner, and readable and writeable for its group and others. You can see the owner and group of a file by running `ls -ld file` (the `-d` is only necessary if it's a directory; without that flag, `ls` shows the content of the directory rather than the directory itself) or if you want less irrelevant information, use `stat`:

```
stat -c '%U %G' file
```

`-c` means control the output. `%U` = file owner, `%G` = group. `file` should be replaced with the path to the file whose metadata you want to examine. If it's in the current directory, its name is sufficient, but you can give a path for files elsewhere:

```
$ stat -c '%U %G' /var/log/syslog
syslog adm
```

The `stat` command can also show file permissions in octal and in "human readable" form:

```
stat -c '%n %a %A' *
```

(I used `%n` to display the filenames, and `*` to run `stat` on every non-hidden file in the current directory.)

This provides a very useful reference if you ever forget what permission bits a particular octal number represents to `chmod`, though [vidarlo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027004/527764) provides a nice way to recall them.

I strongly recommend examining permissions of any file you care about before you change them, since you won't have any way to "reset" the original mode except setting it manually.

Other answers have explained how to set the file mode you need in octal notation. `chmod` accepts file mode in symbolic notation as well as octal, and this is useful when you only want to modify one permission bit (one letter in that `rwxr-xr-x` string). [Perl Duck's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027015/527764) explains how to do this to set the mode you want.

When I create a script and I want to make it executable, which is the main reason I use `chmod`, I use symbolic notation to give myself execute permission and make no other changes, with this command:

```
chmod u+x file
```

If the script needs to be executable by all users, I would run that without `u`:

```
chmod +x file
```

This would probably be sufficient in your current situation, since files are often created by default with permissions that allow reading and writing by the owner and only readable for group and others, but it's also likely that they are created with write permission for the group. This depends on the [`umask`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work) setting a user has when they create the file. Let's create a file and take a look at it!

```
$ touch somefile
$ stat -c '%a %A' somefile 
664 -rw-rw-r--
```

OK. So to get mode `755` I need to remove the `w` bit from the `g` section, and add the `x` bit everywhere.

In symbolic notation, I can do that this way:

```
$ chmod +x,g-w somefile 
$ stat -c '%a %A' somefile 
755 -rwxr-xr-x
```

Another way to write `+x` in `chmod` is `a+x`. `a` stands for all, which is assumed if no letter is given. Important to note: `u` stands for user, which means the owner, while `o` stands for others (*not* owner).

You can also set all the bits for `a` `u` `g` or `o` with the `=` sign. Here's me playing around with useless permission settings:

```
$ chmod =x somefile 
$ stat -c '%a %A' somefile 
111 ---x--x--x
$ chmod u=r,g=rwx,o= somefile 
$ stat -c '%a %A' somefile 
470 -r--rwx---
```

You can use both octal and symbolic notation to add special bits like setuid (this allows running a program as its owner, so is dangerous) and setgid (this causes files created in a directory with setgid subsequently to inherit the directory's group ownership, which is useful because it allows you to control permissions for a group of users in a certain filesystem location without having to constantly fiddle with it).

Some folks like octal notation, some like symbolic. The latter is a little more flexible and maybe a little more intuitive for some. I recommend testing and learning both (safely!) so you'll be able to figure out what any `chmod` command will do when you see it, and solve any homework problem about it with flair :)

#### TL;DR

- Be careful with `chmod`. Don't use `sudo chmod` unless you know what you're doing. Think carefully before using the `-R` flag.
- Look at the existing permissions first. `stat` is your friend
- Learn both symbolic and octal notation.

Answer (score 4):

I find it easiest to think in octal permissions:

- 1 equals execute
- 2 equals write
- 4 equals read

This can easily be seen setting it up bitwise:

```
r w x
0 0 1 #Execute = 1
0 1 0 #Write = 2
1 0 0 #Read = 4
1 0 1 #Read + Execute = 5
1 1 0 #Read + Write = 6
1 1 1 #All permissions = 7
```

These can be added. Read and execute is 4+1=5. Read, execute and write is 7 (4+2+1), write only is 2, and so forth.

There's three digits to the permissions: User, Group and Other. rwx for user becomes 7 (full permissions) for first digit. r-x for group becomes 1+4=5, and r-x for other becomes 5. Thus this equals permissions 755.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for `chmod` command is :

```
chmod [options] {permissions} file-name
```

Before setting the file/folder permissions you need to be in the `Parent Directory` of the file/folder.

```
 r(read) - 4 
 w(write) - 2
 x(execute) - 1
```

Now, analyzing the set from your work: **(-rwxr-xr-x)**

Divide it into four parts as :

**1.** -   `File Type`

**2.** rwx  `User`

**3.** r-x  `Group`

**4.** r-x  `Others`

Thus, Finally to give permision to your file :

**2.** rwx : 4+2+1 = 7

**3.** r-x : 4+0+1 = 5

**4.** r-x : 4+0+1 = 5

Hence, The command is

```
  chmod 755 *filename*
```