# umask (octal form) and umask -S (symbolic form) outputs are different. why?

Tags: permissions, default, umask

Related to file and directory permissions and umask: Why the command umask (shows the octal form) and `umask -S` (shows the symbolic form) show different (actually the option `-S` shows the bits negations of the octal form)? I was expecting the umask in symbolic form for `umask 024` to be `u=---,g=w,o=r` but it shows like this:

```
[user1@server-base ~]$ umask
0024
[user1@server-base ~]$ umask -S
u=rwx,g=rx,o=wx
```

[image: Terminal window]

Comment: Partially. I mean it explains the use of umask and how the default permissions are obtained from base/initial permissions and umask. But why umask -S output shows the negation of umask output.

Comment: This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/783144/986805) explains it best.

Comment: @YAZ84 It's not the negation but the resulting permissions. Go with your example: `umask 024`  `777 - 024` results in `753` which is `u=rwx,g=rx,o=wx`.

Comment: [source](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/builtins/umask.def#L146) says: *Print the umask in a symbolic form.  In the output, a letter is
   printed if the corresponding bit is clear in the umask.* so it's seems to be by design.