# My ubuntu default permissions suddenly changed from 644 to 664?

Tags: 20.10

My ubuntu default permissions suddenly changed from 644 to 664?

Usually, I am familiar with the permissions 644 and 755 for files and directories respectively.

But now when I create a new dir or a new file, the permissions are 664 and 775.

Is 664 and 775 the default permissions actually? But, I haven't noticed them before because I do not really look at file permissions every day.

Even folders created with nautilus do this. And, as there is no button to create a file in nautilus, I use the command line, and I am pretty familiar with the terminal.

I am using Ubuntu 20.10 Minimal Desktop version.

Now this is what happens:

```
$ ls -la
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 exampleuser exampleuser 4096 Mar  5 12:22 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 exampleuser exampleuser 4096 Mar  5 12:23 ..
$ mkdir example
$ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 exampleuser exampleuser 4096 Mar  5 12:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 exampleuser exampleuser 4096 Mar  5 12:23 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 exampleuser exampleuser 4096 Mar  5 12:25 example
```

Comment: Did you look up permissions in the man pages?

Comment: @David, `man chmod`?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work "Starting in Ubuntu Oneiric (11.10) the default umask was relaxed to 002, which expands write-access to the owner's group:"  So either you changed the umask settings or your memory is bad (since we changed to 002 (=chmod 664) in 2010 ;-) )

Comment: @Rinzwind, uhh... many files are 644 still.. that is my confusion. Many system files

Comment: @Exampleperson for root user or when using sudo it's still 644 for files and 755 for directories.

Comment: @mook765, post that as an answer. That clears my doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the default umask which is different for normal users and the root user.

Check the umask for normal user:

```
$ umask
0002
```

which results in 775 for directories and 664 for files.

For the root user:

```
$ sudo su
# umask
0022
```

which results in 755 for directories and 644 for files.

Comment: its the same for me too :O