# How to mark a software as executable in Ubuntu 22.10?

Tags: games, minecraft

I've trying to install TLauncher for play minecraft, the steps says to put the .jar archive in as executable, but I'm very new in Linux systems. I tried to go in properties, but not found what I looking for. I hope someone helps me. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "chmod +x <filename>" do and how do I use it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443789/what-does-chmod-x-filename-do-and-how-do-i-use-it)

Answer (score 1):

In Nautilus (Files) right click file > Properties > Permissions > Check "Allow executing file as program".

Or with command line `chmod +x path/to/filename.jar`

Comment: It didn't work. I think it's better downgrade for now, don't have nothing in my PC. Maybe later I put a newer version of ubuntu. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I had the same problem here's the solution i founded and worked for me in ubuntu 23.04

So I couldn't also see execute as program when I go to properties using GUI but here's the catch when you are doing chmod +x and the file location you may not entering the .jar file instead the folder so here's what you should do

1. Download tlauncher
2. Extract
3. Goto that extracted folder
4. Right click and click open in terminal
5. In terminal write

> sudo chmod +x TLau

and just enter tab it will automatically fill the rest

Enjoy