# How can I get octal file permissions from command line?

Tags: command-line, permissions

There is a **chmod** command to set file permissions, but can I get file permissions in octal mode (such as 755) from the command line?

Comment: For people like me who accidentally landed on this page but actually were searching for how to do this on Mac: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14855227/470749

Comment: `stat --format "%A" $FILE` gives you the human readable `drwxr-x---` format. which may or may not be useful.

Answer (score 717, accepted):

You can try

```
stat -c "%a %n" *
```

Replace `*` with the relevant directory or the exact filename that you want to examine.

From the [man page of stat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/stat.1.html),

```
-c  --format=FORMAT
          use  the  specified  FORMAT instead of the default; output a newline after
          each use of FORMAT
%a     Access rights in octal
%n     File name
```

**Usage:**

- With files:

  ```
  $ stat -c "%a %n" ./Documents/Udev.html 
  664 ./Documents/Udev.html
  ```
- With folders:

  ```
  $ stat -c "%a %n" ./Documents/
  755 ./Documents/
  ```

[(Reference)](http://thenubbyadmin.com/2012/02/16/how-to-list-linux-file-permissions-in-octal-notation/)

Comment: on mac os, use `stat -f '%A %a %N' *` (credit: http://geeklog.adamwilson.info/article/58/getting-file-permissions-in-octal-on-OS-X)

Comment: If you are more comfortable with `ls`: `for f in $(ls -a); do stat -c "%a %n" $f; done;`

Comment: @usandfriends looping on the output of `ls` is a bad idea. If you really want to use a loop you can do `for f in *; do stat "%a %n" "$f"; done`

Comment: ```stat -c "%a %n" `find . -true -print` ``` to recurse into directories. ```cd /etc ; stat -c "%a %n" `find . -true -print` | while read line ; do cd /mnt/broken/etc ; chmod $line ; done ``` to copy permissions (e.g. after a runaway `chmod -R` accident).

Comment: Why on mac os everything is slightly changed (even in unix iso utils)? Is there an actual reason of this?

Comment: Please @hackel, tell us how you really feel.  lol!

Comment: @Vassilis Answer: Know. The question you're really asking is: "if BSD came out before Linux, why did Linux change the standards instead of following the pattern set by older UNIX systems?".

Comment: @hackel: You could have saved time by Googling the history of GNU tools, before making the false suggestion that BSD systems chose to not follow Linux. You have it backwards.

Comment: note in zsh, stat is a built-in shell command therefore use /usr/bin/stat -c '%a' file instead (specifying the whole path to the real stat command)

Comment: to show hidden files + show files attribute with colour + show octal permission with representation, you can check out my answer which uses only short keyword.

Comment: It might be worth adding, that you can also just call `stat <filename>` without the formatting argument (as shown in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/666106/326100)).  You will get more output as needed but when just checking manually, that may not be an issue and you don't need to remember the exact formatting options.

Answer (score 68):

File permissions in Linux can be displayed in octal format using Linux stat command.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, Navigate to the directory where you want to find the file permissions in octal mode.

```
stat -c '%A %a %n' *
```

%A Access rights in human readable form

%a Access rights in octal

%n File name

> Octal numbers and permissions
>
> You can use octal number to represent mode/permission:
>
> ```
> r: 4
> w: 2
> x: 1
> ```
>
> For example, for file owner you can use octal mode as follows. Read,
>   write and execute (full) permission on a file in octal is 0+r+w+x =
>   0+4+2+1 = 7
>
> Only Read and write permission on a file in octal is 0+r+w+x = 0+4+2+0
>   = 6
>
> Only read and execute permission on a file in octal is 0+r+w+x =
>   0+4+0+1 = 5
>
> Use above method to calculate permission for group and others. Let us
>   say you wish to give full permission to owner, read & execute
>   permission to group, and read only permission to others, then you need
>   to calculate permission as follows: User = r+w+x = 0+4+2+1 = 7 Group=
>   r+w+x = 0+4+2+0 = 6 Others = r+w+x = 0+0+0+1 = 1
>
> Effective permission is 761.

Source: http://kmaiti.blogspot.com/2011/09/umask-concept.html

Comment: The initial 0 represent special bit too: http://pastebin.com/6ymkFt71

Comment: is it possible to force 4 digit output?

Comment: To include hidden files/folders starting with dot (eg. _.git_) you can use `stat -c '%A %a %n' .* *`

Answer (score 44):

As detailed in [*“755”-style permissions with ‘ls’*](http://agileadam.com/ls-al-octal-permissions) by [Adam Courtemanche](https://www.linkedin.com/pub/adam-courtemanche/6/8a5/197) on [AgileAdam.com](http://agileadam.com/), you can create [an alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) `lso` that acts like `ls -l` but slightly processes the output<sup>**1**</sup> to display permissions also in octal. This adds a leading column showing three-digit<sup>**2**</sup> octal permissions. As written, this works for most files and directories, but it does not work properly if the [sticky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit) or [setuid/setgid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) bits are set.<sup>**3**</sup>

```bsh
alias lso="ls -alG | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr(\$1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(\" %0o \",k);print}'"
```

This has a serious shortcoming, though, as [techtonik](https://askubuntu.com/users/51852/techtonik) [points out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line/152005#comment674829_152005). You [cannot pass arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Aliases) to this `lso` alias as you would to [the `ls` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/ls.1.html), because they are taken as additional arguments to [`awk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/gawk.1.html) instead. Thus you cannot run `lso` on a specific file or directory, nor can you pass any options (like `-F`, or `--color`) to `lso`.

---

The fix is to define `lso` [as a *function*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) rather than an alias.

```bsh
lso() { ls -alG "$@" | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(" %0o ",k);print}'; }
```

If you're trying this out interactively in your shell, run `unalias lso` to remove the alias--you can do that either before or after you define the function. If you're putting it into a file that is sourced, such as `~/.bashrc`, just take out the `alias` line and add the function definition.

*Why does this work?* Unlike aliases, [bash shell functions can take positional parameters](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands#Functions), i.e., [command-line arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments). [`"$@"` expands to the full argument list](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters), causing arguments to the `lso` function to be passed to `ls`. (Unlike an alias definition, a function body is not quoted; hence it was necessary to remove the `\`characters before `$` and `"`.)

Since you can pass options to `lso` when defined this way as a function, you may wish to remove the `-a` and `-G` options from the definition--you can pass them manually in cases where you want them. ([The `-l` option is required for details like file permissions to be shown *at all*](https://gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#What-information-is-listed), so there is no benefit to removing it.)

```bsh
lso() { ls -l "$@" | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(" %0o ",k);print}'; }
```

***Thanks to [techtonik](https://askubuntu.com/users/51852/techtonik) for [pointing out the limitation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line/152005#comment674829_152005) in defining `lso` as an alias, thus motivating me to expand this post with material about making it a function instead.***

---

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>One may note this seems to flout [the general rule about not parsing output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). `ls` produces very human-readable output; this introduces idiosyncrasies and limitations making it generally unsuitable as input for other commands. *In this case* we parse `ls` since *we wish to preserve the exact behavior of `ls`* except our *one* added change.</sub>

<sup>**2**</sup><sub>One limitation of this alias, which also applies to the function version shown below it, and which may be considered a bug, is that it only displays three octal digits *even when the fourth octal digit is zero.* As [jfmercer](https://askubuntu.com/users/432113/jfmercer) has [rightly pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line/152005#comment935578_526740), the octal digits displayed here don't reflect the sticky bit if present, nor setuid or setgid bits.</sub>

<sup>**3**</sup><sub>More seriously than merely not showing the fourth octal digit is that this method *assumes* they are not set, and **if they are--if you see `t`, `s`,  or `S` in the permission string--then you should disregard the octal digits**. This because the bits are inferred from the permissions string in a way that does not account for sticky setuid/setgid bits.</sub>

Comment: doesn't work with directories - `awk: read error (Is a directory)`

Comment: @techtonik Thanks for pointing this out! I've (finally) updated this answer to include a fix for that.

Comment: You can add `--color` parameter for show colors `lso() { ls -alG "$@" --color | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/)*2^(8-i));if(k)printf(" %0o ",k);print}'; }`

Comment: have you discovered a solution to the sticky setuid/setgid issue since posting this?

Answer (score 29):

Just extending\simplifying previous 'stat' related answers:

**You can simply run:**

```
stat <path_to_file>
```

The output will contain octal permission along with other info.

**Details(stat version and example):**

```
# stat --version
stat (GNU coreutils) 8.4
```

```
[user@localhost ~]# touch /tmp/TEST_PERMISSONS

[user@localhost ~]# chmod 644 /tmp/TEST_PERMISSONS

[user@localhost ~]# stat /tmp/TEST_PERMISSONS
  File: `/tmp/TEST_PERMISSONS'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 1010058     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-08-26 18:58:59.000000000 +0300
Modify: 2015-08-26 18:58:59.000000000 +0300
Change: 2015-08-26 18:59:16.000000000 +0300
```

Note the: (***0644***/-rw-r--r--)

Answer (score 11):

For portability, you can use `perl`:

```
$ perl -e 'printf "%04o %s\n", (stat)[2] & 07777, $_ for @ARGV' *.txt
0644 1.txt
0644 2.txt
0644 3.txt
0644 4.txt
0600 PerlOneLiner.txt
0664 perl.txt
```

If you want to notice when an error occurs, try:

```
perl -e '
for (@ARGV) {
    print "$!: $_\n" and next unless -e;
    printf "%03o %s\n", (stat)[2] & 07777, $_;
}
' *.txt
```

Comment: In addition to being portable, @cuonglm's solution shows _four_ octal characters rather than _three_, thus showing the state of the "sticky bit" that is often forgotten about.

Comment: how about show hidden files ?

Comment: @MaXi32 use `.*`

Answer (score 4):

#### You can use `find` with the `-printf` action.

`ls` doesn't show octal permissions, but you can use this `find`-based workaround:

```bash
find path -printf "%m:%f\n"
```

For example, to check my Videos directory:

```
$ find Videos -printf "%m:%f\n"
755:Videos
```

The `%m` format specifier tells the `-printf` action to print octal permissions, while the `%f` format specifier causes it to print the filename.

You can pass multiple filenames to `find`. You can even use globs (e.g., `find * -printf "%m:%f\n"`).

You don't have to use a test like `-name` or `-iname`; it is sufficient to pass the names of the files or directories you are interested in as starting points to `find`. That is, supply their names as arguments immediately after the word `find`, as shown above.

`find` gives you great control over how it shows output. There are two modifications in particular that you might find useful:

- By default, `find` recurses subdirectories, similar to `ls -R`. If you don't want `find` to visit the subdirectories of the starting points you pass to it, you can add `-maxdepth 0` (or use `-maxdepth` with other values to indicate how deep you want it to go).

  ```
  $ find Documents -maxdepth 0 -printf "%m:%f\n"
  755:Documents
  ```
- `%f` only shows a filename, so if `find` has to recurse to get to a file, you might not know where it is located. To show a path, beginning with whichever starting point the file was found under, use `%p` instead.

  ```
  $ find /boot -printf "%m:%p\n"
  755:/boot
  644:/boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-92-generic
  600:/boot/System.map-4.4.0-93-generic
  600:/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-92-generic
  600:/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
  ....
  ```

See [`man find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html) for more information about using the `find` command.

#### Another Method (`ls` and `awk`)

This can be used to list all directory files with their permissions:

```
ls -l | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
             *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}'
```

This is essentially the same command as in [Adam Courtemanche's `lso` alias](http://agileadam.com/ls-al-octal-permissions), which [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/152005/22949) cited, just run as a single command. If you're only using this once, or on rare occasion, then you might not want to bother writing it as an alias or shell function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias that will show listing somewhat similar to "ls":

```
alias lm='stat -c "%-05a %-12A %-5U %5G %s   %-015F %n" * | numfmt --to=iec --field=5 --padding=6'
```