# Font Viewer not running in Ubunt 16.04 latest version

Tags: fonts

Downloaded and installed Ubuntu 16.04 from the Ubuntu website 3 days ago. Updated the OS using commands in terminal. I need to install a font Rachana.ttf, which is available on my computer's desktop. But Font Viewer not running? It just shows the busy cursor spinning, but eventually does nothing? Is there a fix? 
Even though i right click on the font, the listed menu doesn't show "install font"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install many font files quickly and easily?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191778/how-to-install-many-font-files-quickly-and-easily)

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to get the latest fixed version of `gnome-font-viewer`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with this [issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-font-viewer/+bug/1607937).
Try to update `gnome-font-viewer`. Latest version is `3.16.2`.

To check version.

```
gnome-font-viewer --version
```

If your gnome-font-viewer version is old, update with following command.

```
sudo apt install gnome-font-viewer
```

After update try to open your font again.