# How to install .FON fonts in Linux using wine

Tags: wine, fonts

I have some `.FON` format fonts I want to install in my Linux, i.e. put them in `/usr/share/fonts` so that I can see them appearing in fc-list. But these fonts are in executable form. I downloaded and installed wine but I cannot even install them with wine, so how can I do it?

I have seen some other questions related to this but in my case i dont want to convert .fon to sfd or so i wan to use them as is because i want to test FreeType windows font drivers module

Comment: Read this first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191778/how-to-install-many-font-files-quickly-and-easily . Now, a Windows installer most likely won't work but those (for fonts) are usually just a self-extracting rar, zip or similar. If so it can be opened by an archive manager and extracted, one of the folders containing the fonts files.

Comment: @karel i dont want to convert .fon to sfd or so i wan to use them as is because i want to test FreeType windows font drivers module

Comment: @CelticWarrior Actually i extracted the same way and copied in my /usr/share/fonts and even in ~/.fonts,
but hey dont appear in (fc-list) after i manually rebuild the font cache (fc-cache -f -v), so i can immediately use them everywhere.

Comment: @EricCarvalho HOW MY QUE IS POSSIBLE DUPLICATE? did i ask how can i convert a .FON to.PCF?