# How to reverse file ownership and permission settings

Tags: permissions, directory, lamp

I installed LAMP and WordPress on my system a week ago. Since I couldn't create Child Themes in WordPress and work with PHP folders for my other projects collocated in var/www without using Nautilus I wanted to solve the permissions issue.

I hoped to bring a solution carrying out the commands on this page for my WordPress folder: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FileSystemPermissions.

This allowed me to play with any file in the folder like creating and modifying .css files through WP Admin, etc. But after a restart I discovered that I can't change DNS settings of my network connections in the list anymore because it is asking me the root password and even though I enter the password it doesn't let me do the action giving "insufficient privileges" error.

Can you help me correct the mistake I possibily made during the configuration and, maybe, configure again the permission and ownership settings for var/www/somefolder as it is adviced to be configured under general circumstances?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I fear, you can't reverse the change unless you saved the permission settings somewhere.

I recommend this, Install the same softwares in another machine, check the permissions there, copy them and use the same permissions for your machine to correct the errors.

- Check this question : [How can I get octal file permissions from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you ran the commands in the link you gave, simply run

```
sudo -R chown www-data:www-data /var/www
```

You should know that by default, ubuntu uses www-data as the apache (and other http servers) user/group.

See also:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP