# How can I check the folder permissions in ubuntu server 12.04?

Tags: server, permissions, directory, chmod

Right now, I know that I can change permissions for example with:

```
sudo chmod 550 directory
```

I wonder how I can check the actual folder permission.

Comment: Do you specifically need to see the permissions in octal (like `550`), or is any format that shows them unambiguously sufficient? (If you don't need them in octal, then [Radu Rădeanu's way](http://askubuntu.com/a/332449/22949) is the normal way to do this.)

Comment: is there a way to see them octal ? have you heard about that? right now it displays : lrwxrwxrwx , so it means : read and write for everybody, correct?

Comment: Yes, there are a few techniques for this. See [How can I get octal file permissions from command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152001/how-can-i-get-octal-file-permissions-from-command-line)

Comment: even more stupid :D haha. thank you very much. I suddenly liked this way much more :)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use the following command:

```
ls -l directory
```

or

```
stat directory
```

or, if you want to see only the permissions in numeric (octal) format:

```
stat -c %a directory
```

Answer (score -2):

### "Destination folder is not writable or does not exists."

*on Magento 2.3.1 admin on NGINX  Ubuntu 16.04 | AWS Ec2*

Solution I Found

> ```
> cd /var/www/html/pub/media
> ```

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

add media folder to permissions