# Why I can't access any folder in ubuntu?

Tags: directory

I cannot access any folder in my pc. It shows me `You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of ..`
But I can access using `sudo nautilus`.  I feel bored to type it frequently. How can I access my folder without any permission? I partitioned my home into 4 partition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i check the folder permissions in ubuntu server 12.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/332434/how-can-i-check-the-folder-permissions-in-ubuntu-server-12-04)

Comment: You have read access to most folders by default. Which exact folders do you want to access?

Answer (score 1):

Use the command

```
chown -R yourusername /home/yourusername
```

What this does is takes ownership (for your user account) of all files and directories within your home directory.

You inherently cannot access some files and folders via your user-specific Nautilus. To access those you must either take ownership or change permissions of them, or use `gksudo` or `sudo`.

To read/write/execute certain files/folders, use the `chmod` command.

```
chmod -R (permissions)
```

The permission can be calculated by this:

Execute by user is 100. 
Execute by group is 010. Execute by all is 001.
Write by user is 200. Write by group is 020. Write by all is 002.
Read by user is 400. Read by group is 040. Read by all is 004.

Therefore, we will use

```
chmod -R 700
```

You, the owner, can read, write, and execute.

**Be careful what and how you chmod! Giving certain permissions to all groups and users can be very unsafe!**

Comment: And how is this helping?

Comment: @heemayl OP doesn't have permission to access his files in his home folder.

Comment: Op says _I cannot access any folder in my pc_

Comment: @heemayl By nature of Nautilus you cannot access some files and folders with Nautilus. Using "sudo nautilus" like OP says works, but at least he will have GUI access to his home folder without sudo, which is how it's supposed to work.