# is there ls -l numeric formating?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, ls

consider the output of this ls -l command:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | tail
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     105696 Oct 25  2014 zenity
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     188296 Oct 21  2013 zip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      86096 Oct 21  2013 zipcloak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      48459 Mar  3  2015 zipdetails
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       2953 Oct 29 10:45 zipgrep
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root     166584 Oct 29 10:45 zipinfo
```

the permissions are listed in the nice, human readable characters.
Is there a way to get `ls`  to output the numerical equivalent to those permissions?

Comment: What do you intend to use the octal values for? Further processing, or just to look at?

Comment: Very much related question: [How can I get octal file permissions from command line?](http://askubuntu.com/q/152001/295286)

Comment: And this one on U&L site : [Convert ls -l output format to chmod format](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71585/85039)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls` does not have such flag, but `stat` command allows showing octal permissions. Consider sample output for a test file,

```
testdir:$ stat TESTER
  File: ‘TESTER’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 1197        Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)   Gid: ( 1000/ xieerqi)
Access: 2015-11-05 17:42:01.914917433 -0700
Modify: 2015-11-05 17:42:01.914917433 -0700
Change: 2015-11-05 18:41:04.463776180 -0700
 Birth: -
```

`stat` also has `--format` flag , which allows you to "simulate" `ls -l` :

```
testdir:$ stat --format="%a %h %U %G %s %y %n" * | head -n 3                   
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42:01.918917452 -0700 Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000003 tag tag_tag 9tag
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42:01.922917471 -0700 Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000004 tag tag_tag 9tag
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42:01.930917509 -0700 Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000005 tag tag_tag 9tag
```

The only limitation here is the time format cannot be altered and color output cannot be added .

You could always alias that command in `.bashrc` to some shorter command, e.g. `alias lsl2='stat --format="%a %h %U %G %s %y %n" *'`

Alternatively, I've put together a small function that uses `find` and `awk` for nicer formatting

```
 function lsl2
   {
     find . -maxdepth 1 | sort |  xargs -I{} stat --format="%a %h %U %G %s %y %n" {}  | awk '{$7=substr($7,1,5);$8    =" ";print}'
  }
```

Sample output

```
testdir:$ lsl2 | head -n 7
775 3 xieerqi xieerqi 4096 2015-11-05 22:20   .
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42   ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000003 tag tag_tag 9tag
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42   ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000004 tag tag_tag 9tag
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42   ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000005 tag tag_tag 9tag
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42   ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000006 tag 9tag
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42   ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000006 tag tag_tag 9tag
664 1 xieerqi xieerqi 0 2015-11-05 17:42   ./Aaaaaaa.bbb - 0000007 tag 9tag

testdir:$ type lsl2
lsl2 is a function
```

Comment: Uh.. `find` can print the permissions, and most of these values (if not all): `find .  -printf "%m %n %u %g %s %t %f\n" | column -t`

Comment: @muru well I didn't know that  . . . .-_- `find` has way too many options . . . Write an answer ! You're gonna have my upvote

Answer (score 4):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795976/can-the-unix-list-command-ls-output-numerical-chmod-permissions it is not possible.

An answer to that question, however proposes a way to 'almost' achieve that:

```
ls -l | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
         *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}'
```

You could make that an alias for easy use - but ls alone can not do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun pipeline

```
paste <(printf "%04d\n" $(stat -c '%a' *)) <(ls -l | sed 1d) | 
  sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+)\t(.)........./\2\1/'
```

- `printf "%04d\n" $(stat -c '%a' *)` -- prints the zero-padded octal access rights for each file
- `ls -l | sed 1d` -- the long listing, minus the first line "total 12345"
- `paste <(...) <(...)` -- takes one line from each process substitution, and joins them with a tab
- `sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]+)\t(.)........./\2\1/'` -- replaces the `rwxrwxrwx` human readable permissions with the octal value.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at GNU find:

```
find -printf "%y %m %n %u %g %Ac %f\n" -maxdepth 1
```

See: `man find`

Answer (score 0):

*Hmm... found this is in searching for something totally else,*

**One more to the collection:**

```
ls -lh \
  | sed -re 's/rwx/7/g' \
         -e 's/rw-/6/g' \
         -e 's/r-x/5/g' \
         -e 's/r--/4/g' \
         -e 's/-wx/3/g' \
         -e 's/-w-/2/g' \
         -e 's/--x/1/g' \
         -e 's/---/0/g'
```